# Return the flipped version of a number

Tags: code-golf, number

When a number is shown on a calculator, it's possible to consider what various transformations of that number would look like. For example, on a seven-segment display, 2 is shown like this:

[image]

And when flipped horizontally it looks like this:

[image]

As such, the mirror image of 2 is 5.

The task in this challenge is to take a single-digit number, and return the number that's its mirror image (if possible). If its mirror image does not look like a number, return the number rotated 180 degrees (if possible). If neither of these are the case, return -1.

Here's the full list of inputs and outputs your program needs to handle:

```
Input   Output
0       0
1       -1
2       5
3       -1
4       -1
5       2
6       9
7       -1
8       8
9       6
```

As a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, the shortest code wins!

Comment: You can submit your own answer to your question, so feel free to add it.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: I disagree with your last point -- a 1 on a 7 segment display would simply be flipped to the other side, so 1 should nap to 1.

Comment: You should specify I/O. Do you want a function, a program or anything specific?

Comment: why wouldn't 8 and 0 return -1?

Comment: I am confused about how to flip each digit. If 2 becomes 5, then 6 should become backwards 9, not 9. But if 6 becomes 9, then the flip is just a rotation, so 2 becomes another 2, not 5.

Comment: @kernigh I think it's meant to be a reflection across a horizontal axis.

Comment: @Cory But the question states that 9 and 6 should flip to 6 and 9. That is not a reflection across the horizontal axis.

Comment: 6, 9 rotated 180 deg, 2, 5 flipped horizontally, and 1, 3 in fact are reflections of themselves across the vertical axis.

Comment: The translations defined in the question are not consistent at all. Why do 2 and 5 flip, but 3 doesn't?

Comment: @Rynant Yeah, `1`, `3`, `6`, and `9` really throw my definition off (foolish positive bias!). I'll pay more attention from here on out. Fortunately, everything but `4` is explicitly spelled out in the challenge. So the rule *is* consistent, but with an extra layer of complexity.

Comment: I noticed a curious fact about the switchable numbers: they form opposite binary patterns, i.e. 2=010, 5=101. 6=0110, 9=1001. Can anyone use this fact in their solution?

Comment: @JackAidley: I guess since the problem is so trivial and, in fact, tailored to `IndexOf`-type methods on strings I doubt this will lead to significant savings.

Comment: Agree. 6 rotated 180 degrees becomes 9 but 2 and 5 rotated 180 degrees become itself again. This should be restated as flipped or rotated version of a number, and 1 should be included in

Comment: 3 should be flipped to E

Comment: Maybe your example should be `6` and `9` because `5` could be flipped horizontally *or* vertically to become `2`

Comment: I've gone and edited the specification to match the answers. Hopefully this challenge can be reopened now.

Answer (score 34):

### Haskell - <s>43</s> 31

43 characters without anything fancy.

```hs
f 0=0
f 8=8
f 2=5
f 5=2
f 6=9
f 9=6
f _= -1
```

Got it down to 31 characters by making it a partial function.

```hs
f=([0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6]!!)
```

Comment: I laughed. Have a +1.

Comment: +1 For using Haskell to do ***exactly*** what the spec. says!

Comment: I don't think you need `f=` for the second solution as it is a valid expression

Answer (score 23):

## GolfScript, <strike>15</strike> 14

I read the spec again and found that the input must be a string.

```
"0.5..29.86"\?
```

To run:

```
echo -n 2 | ruby golfscript.rb a.gs
```

Old version(which has integer input):

```
[0.5..2 9.8 6]?
```

The newer one(14 byte) is somewhat inspired by the [CJam answer by aditsu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31987/).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 20):

### PowerShell - 27

```
'0 5  29 86'.indexof($args)
```

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2.x - 28

```
'015..29.86'.find(`input()`)
```

Comment: Python 2.x, specifically.

Comment: With Python 3, you could remove the `\``s and save 2 chars.

Comment: This is a snippet, not a full program!

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript <s>37</s> 36

```
alert("0_5__29_86".search(prompt()))
```

Comment: use `.search()` and save a byte.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nice one, Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**BEFUNGE 93 - <s>18</s> <s>14</s> 20 Bytes**

I guess the commentators are right, though Befunge being a 2d language lines are kinda different. Still, in this instant, the commentators are right.

```
&1g01g-.  
! &  #* )'
```

Steps:

```
&
```

Reads input as a numerical value x, and pushes it on the stack.

```
1g
```

Gets the character value c (so, like '!' = 33, or '*' = 42. An empty cell = 32) at position x, 1.

```
01g-.
```

Reads the character value of cell 0,1 (33), subtracts it from c, and outputs it as a numerical value.

Comment: Quite nice. Have a +1.

Comment: Please correct the length: it's 20 bytes

Comment: You've actually been counting your bytes wrong. You used **19** bytes. We count newlines and spaces. But if you switch to Befunge 98, you can save one; change 1st line to: `&1g'!-.`

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 20 bytes

```
q25691347`"5296W"er~
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Output

```
$ for i in {0..9}; { cjam <(echo 'q25691347`"5296W"er~') <<< $i; echo; }
0
-1
5
-1
-1
2
9
-1
8
6
```

#### How it works

```
q          " Read from STDIN. The leaves a string on the stack.            ";
25691347`  " Push the string '25691347'.                                   ";
"5296W"    " Push the string '5296W'.                                      ";
er         " Perform character transliteration.                            ";
~          " Evaluate the result. Examples: '2' returns 2, 'W' returns -1. ";
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) 25

```
x=>'1060039097'[x]-(x!=6)
```

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 5) 43

```
function f(x){return'1060039097'[x]-(x!=6)}
```

UPDATE: edc65 has suggested a much better technique. toothbrush has suggested a much better language. At this point, my primary contributions are debugging and gumption.

Comment: If you change it to ECMAScript 6 (supported in Firefox), you could simply do `x=>[0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6][x]`.

Comment: At first, I nearly posted `function(x)[0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6][x]`, also thanks to Firefox. I wasn't going to win anyway, so I decided I'd just stick with the highest-compatibility answer. If I start switching languages for brevity, then I'll eventually start defining my own language for every challenge I do. But I'll go ahead and mention the ECMAScript 6 version anyway, since you suggested it

Comment: Same concept but shorter (bye bye commas): x=>'106003907'[x]-(x!=6)

Comment: @edc65 You know, I'd wanted to use a string, and I had completely blanked on the fact that I could coerce the result back to a number. A bizarre lapse. Yet I still wouldn't have come up with `-(x!=6)`. Thank you.

Comment: [you don't need `f=` unless you are calling `f` recursively or the question explicitly requires a function with a specific name](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/41042)

Comment: @Cyoce Good point.

Answer (score 8):

## Java - 49

```
long f(int a){return(0x790a300601L>>(a*4)&15)-1;}
```

Here, `0x790a300601` is a value stuffed with the desired outputs, with one added to make them positive. The values are stored in nibbles within the value, so a bit of shifting and masking is required to pop them out.

## Java - 100 (fun option)

```
int f(int a){Random r=new Random(0x2000A2F47D6Fl);int b=0;for(;a>=0;a--)b=r.nextInt(11)-1;
return b;}
```

Not the smallest option, but a bit of fun. I found a random seed that produces the correct values when called *X* times (where 0 >= *X* <= 9).

Comment: Clever. Have a +1

Answer (score 6):

## bash 29

```
tr 1-9 x5xx29x86|sed s/x/-1/g
```

e.g.

```
$ echo 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | tr 1-9 x5xx29x86|sed s/x/-1/g
0 -1 5 -1 -1 2 9 -1 8 6
```

Comment: You can omit the `'` around the sed expression.  Also I think you can omit the `g` because the spec only supplies one digit at a time

Comment: Thanks. It's just in the example, the submission itself doesn't use `'`. Liking the `g` for longer input!

Answer (score 4):

## [Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) - 29

This function returns the element `x` from the array `0 -1 5...`

```
f:{0 -1 5 -1 -1 2 9 -1 8 6@x}
```

Examples:

```
> f 2
  5
> f 5
  2
> f 8
  8
```

Comment: Is a vector by itself really allowed?

Comment: @TheRare: Hmm, it does say "algorithm" so I suppose not. I'll change it and make it more like yours...

Comment: Seems better, have a +1.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript 36 <del>37</del> <del>41</del>

```
alert('0x'+'65b558f5ec'[prompt()]-6)
```

as ES6 function - 27:

```
f=v=>'0x'+'65b558f5ec'[v]-6
```

Comment: 28: `f=v=>~-[1,,6,,,3,10,,9,7][v]`

Comment: @nderscore You just love improving people's codes, don't you?

Comment: @TheRare I'm just on a quest to find the shortest javascript code. :) If someone else has already posted a good answer, it makes more sense to me to find optimizations in it rather than post a new answer that's almost a duplicate. I'm not here to compete, just to cooperate towards achieving this goal.

Comment: @nderscore I have the same mentality as long as my idea is similar enough. Anyways, nice one.

Comment: @nderscore You really gave me a motivation. I'm not sure if I can make it shorter, but I'll try :)

Comment: @core1024 clever method!

Answer (score 4):

## Sclipting, 11 characters

```
걄럣뉥밈결⓷方分결剩貶
```

Finally I have found a Windows computer with Visual Studio installed to build its interpreter. And it has defeated my GolfScript code easily.

It reads `18453063256\11\?/11%(` in GolfScript.

Comment: Interesting, but your GolfScript answer still wins. Unless the question states otherwise, length is measured in bytes.

Comment: @Dennis This was my 3rd or 4th answer on this site. I didn't know. And I think APL is an exception.

Comment: @Dennis And most people don't like Sclipting. :)

Comment: Not really an exception, we just let people choose their encoding. This answer would score 22 bytes, since that's its size using UTF-16. APL uses only 256 different characters, and there's an APL code page where once character is exactly one bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 22 bytes

```apl
⊢⌷{1-⍨⎕A⍳'BAGAADKAJH'}
```

Explanation:

```apl
⊢⌷{1-⍨⎕A⍳'BAGAADKAJH'}
      ⎕A⍳'BAGAADKAJH'     ⍝ numeric vector 2 1 7 1 1 4 11 1 10 8
   1-⍨                    ⍝ decrement:     1 0 6 0 0 3 10 0  9 7
⊢⌷                        ⍝ value at index ⍵ in the lut
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OApMajrkWPerZXG@o@6l0BlHJ81LtZ3cnR3dHRxdvRy0O9VhOkAagw7dAKAwVDBSMF4/8A)

Comment: there's an easy -1 byte here.

Comment: commute, I see.

Comment: `1-⍨⎕A⍳⌷∘'BAGAADKAJH'`

Answer (score 3):

## J - <s>28</s> 27 bytes

You know what I like? Simplicity (28 bytes). Note that in J, `_1` is negative one (-1).

```
f=:{&0 _1 5 _1 _1 2 9 _1 8 6
```

Add a little complexity and you have 27 bytes.

```
f=:-{&0 2 _3 4 5 3 _3 8 0 3
```

Example:

```
   f 2
5
   f 6
9
   f 5
2
...
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam - 14

Input/output version:

```
"0 5  29 86"q#
```

Stack version (assumes the number is on the stack):

```
[0W5WWY9W8 6]=
```

Try them at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Comment: There's no Wikipedia article about CJAM, and the link just goes to a blank fiddler.  Where would you find information about the language and its established releases?

Comment: Looks like this is it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/

Comment: @Panzercrisis http://cjam.aditsu.net/ has "CJam" linked to the sourceforge page

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <strike>27</strike> 26

Count includes the `p` flag

```perl
y/2569/5296/,s/[1347]/-1/
```

Usage:

```perl
$ echo 7 | perl -pe y/2569/5296/,s/[1347]/-1/
-1
```

***Wait, did Perl just beat J? :)***

Comment: +1 I was going to post `y+0-9+9a4aa70a13+;$_=9-hex`, which is the same length, but your is more original ;)

Comment: @core1024 : And it just got shorter ;)

Comment: It didn't: `echo 1 | perl -pe y/2569/5296/,s/[347]/-1/`

Comment: @core1024 : I misread the specs, should be fixed now. It's still shorter than the J solution.

Comment: There really is no concise way to do this in J, as values are strictly typed and numbers can't match strings.

Comment: @TheRare : I don't think it'll get much shorter in Perl than this either.

Comment: I actually clocked around triple the characters doing it in this style. Have a +1 for the nice idea.

Comment: `perl -pE "y/2569/5296/or$_=-1"` :)

Comment: @alexander-brett : won't work for `0`

Comment: Sure, could put the 0 in the 'y///' I guess?

Answer (score 3):

### ECMAScript 6, 24

```
f=x=>~-++'0n5nn29n86'[x]
```

Using normal JavaScript it would be 33:

```
alert(~-++'0n5nn29n86'[prompt()])
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang) 34 bytes

```
}0
=6=9=2=5=0=8?0
+3-3+3-3....--
```

It's not the shortest solution, but it's not the longest either.

**How it works**

`}0` spawns a marble representing the first command line input. This marble drops down the next tick, onto the `=6` cell. `=6` is a comparison cell, it pushes any marble with value 6 down and all others to the right. This line-up of comparison cells pushes marbles right until they equal a desired value. 0 and 8 just fall through and get printed when tehy fall off the bottom of the board, 6 and 2, and 9 and 5 first get 3 added to them, subtracted from them respectively. If a marble doesn't equal any of the desired values, it lands on the `?0` cell, which turn any marble into a 0 marble<sup>1</sup>. This marble then gets decremented and falls off the board.

<sub><sup>1</sup> A `?n` marble technically turns any marble into a marble between 0 and n. This has the nice side effect that `?0` turns anything into 0.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB - 35

I would wrap this in a function with `n` as the only parameter.

```
f=[0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6];
f(n+1)
```

35 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>24</s> 22

```
-1+int(11fPart(11^Ans.0954191904
```

This encodes the possible outputs in a lookup table stored as a base-11 floating point number; the (N+1)th base-11 digit after the decimal point is extracted from the table to get the value of the inverted digit. In base 11 the number is `.106003A097`, and the digits of this less one are exactly `0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6`.

edc65's trick of subtracting one in the case of 6 leads to this 24-byte solution, where `⑩^(` is a single one-byte token:

```
-(Ans≠6)+int(10fPart(.1060039097⑩^(Ans
```

The string approach is 29 bytes:

```
-(Ans≠6)+expr(inString("1060039097",Ans+1,1
```

The array approach (which Ypnpyn also took) is 30 bytes, assuming the number is stored in X:

```
{1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}-1:Ans(X+1
```

24 -> 22: Removed two extra digits of precision in the magic constant.

Comment: This can almost certainly be golfed to 19, and possibly to 18; however, I need to search for the correct numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## C - 47 bytes [was 48 Bytes]

```
f(i){return(int[]){1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}[i]-1;}
```

To add I/O (which other answers didn't always) for 86 bytes:

```
main(i){i=(int[]){1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}[getchar()-48]-1;i<0?puts("-1"):putchar(i+48);}
```

Comment: Wow, I had no clue inline array literals like this were a thing. Very nice first answer, and welcome to PPCG! (There is no need to add I/O [function submissions are perfectly valid](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422).)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
0®5®®Y9®8 6¹@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29waJ3poXWH1kVaHlpnoWB2aKfD//@WX/PydZMTkzNSAQ)

-3 thanks to [Emigna](/users/47066).

Explanation:

```
0®5®®Y9®8 6¹@ Takes an integer from STDIN.
0®5®®Y9®8 6   Push 0, r=-1, 5, r=-1, r=-1, Y=2, 9, r=-1, 8, 6.
           ¹  Push first input item.
            @ Pop and push the 0-indexed stack item at the respective index.
```

Comment: `0®5®®Y9®8 6¹@` should work as well.

Comment: @Emigna I had no idea, thanks!

Comment: Good thinking with `@`. Not often you see that used :)

Comment: @Emigna A byte shorter than `)¹è` or `)sè`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 34

```
f=lambda n:ord("A@F@@CJ@IG"[n])-65
```

Comment: 33 `f=lambda n:ord(" "[n])-3` working with space http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user34_Q7NbNvQy55_0.py

Comment: You might want to explain how and why this works

Comment: Using the ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/ the white spaces chosen are printable in python. it actually looks something like `&#002;&#002;&#008;&#002;&#002;&#005;&#012;&#002;&#011;&#009;` It's minus 3 for the reason that -1 leaves a null character which is no good, and minus 2 leaves a line feed which is reserved in python

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 58 <s>59</s>

```
int f(int i){int[]a={1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7};return a[i]-1;}
```

OR

```
int f(int i){return new int[]{1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}[i]-1;}
```

Comment: You can make your code a bit shorter if you add 1 to each value in array and after [i] substract 1.

Comment: @Barteks2x Good point; thanks

Answer (score 1):

## C - <strike>117</strike> <strike>108</strike> <strike>106</strike> <strike>77</strike> 76 bytes

```
a[]={1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7};main(int c,char**b){printf("%d",a[*b[1]-48]-1);}
```

Not the best language for golfing, but oh well...
Compile with `gcc progname.c -o progname`.  (Ignore the warnings, or add `-include stdio.h` to the compile command.)

> Usage: ./progname <number>

**EDIT**

As per @bebe's suggestion, here is an example that takes the input from STDIN instead:

## C - <strike>68</strike> 51 bytes

```
main(){printf("%d","106003:097"[getchar()-48]-49);}
```

Comment: using `d=*b[1]-48` could be a good idea

Comment: @bebe Ah yes, thanks!

Comment: `main(){printf("%d",(int[]){1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}[getchar()-48]-1);}` sorry for bothering you this much but i find this a bit shorter.

Comment: You can save another character by making the array global so you don't need the cast. `a[]={1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7};main(){printf("%d",a[getchar()-48]-1);}`

Comment: `main(){printf("%d","106003:097"[getchar()-48]-49);}` 51 bytes

Comment: @bebe Wow, you are a lot better golfer than me!!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript <strike>42</strike> 37

Run it on the console of your browser

```
alert(~-[1,,6,,,3,10,,9,7][prompt()])
```

Answer (score 1):

## J (24, function)

(the input panel isn't playing nice. Paste the following in a python interpreter and my answer shall be revealed:)

```
print "f=:{&(_3+3 u:'^C^B^B^E^L^B^K\t')"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure - 36

```
#(case % 2 5 5 2 6 9 9 6 0 0 8 8 -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 22B

`perl -pe "y/25690/52960/or$_=-1"`

Based off https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32012/19039, but shorter. 1B penalty for -p.

Answer (score 1):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), 40 bytes (noncompeting)

```
!.(3'1)(4'1)(1l'-)(2'5l)(5'2)(6'9l)(9'6)
```

**[Try it online!](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=IS4oMycxKSg0JzEpKDFsJy0pKDInNWwpKDUnMikoNic5bCkoOSc2KQ&input=Ng)**

Explanation

```
!                                          take input
 .                                         write first char of input to cell
  (3'1)                                    if cell is 3, write 1
       (4'1)                               if cell is 4, write 1
            (1l'-)                         If cell is 1, move left and write -
                  (2'5l)                   If cell is 2, write 5 and move left
                        (5'2)              If cell is 5, write 2
                             (6'9l)        If cell is 6, write 9 and move left
                                   (9'6)   If cell is 9, write 6
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ị“-5--29-860”V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/ejhjm6prq6Rpa6FmYGjxrmhv3//98SAA)

Explanation:

```
ị“-5--29-860”V Takes argument as an integer.
 “-5--29-860”  "-5--29-860" (1-indexed string).
ị              Return the xth char of the string above (y) (x=argument).
             V Eval. - is the same as -1.
```

Comment: `ịV = žh‡` in 05AB1E

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>48</s> 39 bytes

Thanks to [Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%C3%B6rg-h%C3%BClsermann)

```php
<?=[0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6][$argv[1]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCj4r5Jrq2tonZqcka8QbaCjkqtjCiKAyEjHEkRZ6JjFRqskFqWXRRvGxlpz/f//3xQA)

---

**Older versions**

```php
$m=-1;echo [0,$m,5,$m,$m,2,9,$m,8,6][$argv[1]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCj4r5Jrq2tonZqcka8QbaCjkqtjCiKAyEjHEkRZ6JjFRqskFqWXRRvGxlpz/f//3xQA)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Even better, should I post?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
kd`0u5uu29u86`⇿ₑ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kd%600u5uu29u86%60%E2%87%BF%E2%82%91&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Simply push the digits 0 to 9, push the string `0u5uu29u86` (the mapping of each number - `u` pushes -1 in Vyxal), transliterate and evaluate as Vyxal.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 31 bytes

```
=MID(1060039097,A1+1,1)-(A1<>6)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.11 - 24

```
lambda x:"0.5..29.86"[x]
```

Based on [this Python 2.x answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/return-the-flipped-version-of-a-number/31965) by Willem.

Answer (score 0):

## **Python - 92**

```
f=lambda x:x if x in(0,8)else(5if x==2 else(2if x==5 else(6if x==9 else(9if x==6 else -1))))
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(2)
5
>>> f(3)
-1
```

Comment: def f(x): will make it a byte shorter.

Also "[a,b][x==5]" is shorter then and equivalent to "a if x==5 else b"

Comment: Also, a small change would be to put the if x==9 last and say x>8 instead, saving a character.

Comment: @Pinna_be: You’re forgetting the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

### Python - 73 bytes

```
r=[2,5,2,9,6,9,8,8,0,0]
f=lambda x:-1 if x not in r else r[r.index(x)+1]
```

Or, for one digit numbers only :

```
r=[0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6]
f=lambda x:r[x]
```

Comment: why not altogether `f=(lambda x:[-1,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6][x])(x)`

Comment: 43 `def f(x):print[-1,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6][x]`

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 75

```
int f(int i){return i>8?6:i>7?8:i>6?-1:i>5?9:i>4?2:i>2?-1:i>1?5:i>0?-1:0;}
```

Comment: `i>8:-1` will return -1 for input 9 when it should return 6, won't it?

Comment: @corsiKa Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell 32

```
(0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6)[$args]
```

Answer (score 0):

## F# - 37 bytes

```
let f n=[0;-1;5;-1;-1;2;9;-1;8;6].[n]
```

Usage:

```
> f 2
val it : int = 5
> f 9
val it : int = 6
> f 4
val it : int = -1
```

Comment: Fails for 0 and 8

Comment: I missed that in the rules, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 35

```
{1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}→L1:L1(X+1)-1
```

Previous attempt, 42:

```
6(X=2)+3(X=5)+10(X=6)+9(X=8)+7(X=9)-1+(X=0
```

Comment: 30 bytes: `{1,0,6,0,0,3,10,0,9,7}-1:Ans(X+1`

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 85

Uses nested ternary statements.

```
int main(){int a;cin>>a;a=(a==2)?5:(a==5?2:(a==6?9:(a==9?6:(a%8==0?a:-1))));cout<<a;}
```

Comment: Doesn't C++ inherit the abuse of integers for Booleans of C?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes C++ accepts integers, but I don't want 'a' modified until the end.

Comment: No need to modify `a`. I was thinking that `(a==X)?Y:Z` can be `(a-X)?Z:Y` to save a few bytes.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I can't find a gcc version that accepts that without `#include <iostream>` and `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash 26

```
bc<<<`tr 0-9 106003A097`-1
```

eg.

```
for i in {0..9}; do echo $i|
  bc<<<`tr 0-9 106003A097`-1
done
0
-1
5
-1
-1
2
9
-1
8
6
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3: 47

A very basic implementation, that accepts a input and translates accordingly.

```
print([0,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,9,-1,8,6][int(input())])
```

PEP8 is of course sacrificed for the sake of characters. This doesn't come close to rivaling the other Python solution near the top. However, as my first golf, I don't think it's *that* bad :).

Comment: This could be written `print[0,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,9,-1,8,6][input()]` in Python 2. Also one could increase all the numbers by 1 to save one character.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (full program), 63

```
main=interact$maybe"-1"(:"").(`lookup`zip"025689""052986").head
```

Call main, and whatever character your input starts with gets used. Anything that isn't '0', '2', '5', '6', '8', or '9' prints "-1". Unfortunately `show` wraps characters in single quotes, so the output wouldn't have been consistent, so I had to use `(:"")` (or `(:[])`).

Answer (score 0):

## Batch - 79

```
set /aa=%1+1&for /f "tokens=%a%" %%1 in ("0 -1 5 -1 -1 2 9 -1 8 6") do echo>%%1
```

Used as `filename.bat number`, output is as a file with the name of the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zozotez LISP](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) 87

```scm
((:'f(\(k n v)(? k(?(=(a k)n)(a v)(f(d k)n(d v)))'-1)))'(0 2 5 6 8 9)(r)'(0 5 2 9 8 6))
```

This assumes you start it by seeding one of the REPL supplied so the printing actually is done by Without a driver/REPL you need 3 chars extra:

```scm
(p((:'f(\(k n v)(? k(?(=(a k)n)(a v)(f(d k)n(d v)))'-1)))'(0 2 5 6 8 9)(r)'(0 5 2 9 8 6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

What, no Ruby solution yet?

```
p'0 5  29 86'.index($*[0])||-1
```

Takes the input as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 16 bytes

```
x[ZZ5ZZ2 9Z8 6)Q
```

Doesn't really count because Pyth was created after this was posted, but it's still pretty neat.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## [dimwit](https://github.com/MCMastery/dimwit) <s>24</s> 23 bytes (non-competing)

**Edit:** removed end bracket, as it is not necessary

Another question that I thought could be good for working on the language with...

```
R2,5,6,9,[1-7]}5,2,9,6,-1
```

#### Explanation:

- `R` - map replace
- `2,5,7,9,[1-7]}` - the searches. Since 2, 5, 6, and 9 are checked first, 1-7 can be used and will simply check if it's 1, 3, 4, or 7. 0 and 8 will therefore stay the same.
- `5,2,9,6,-1` - the replacements. So 2 is replaced by 5, 5 is replaced by 2, etc.

#### [Try it Here](http://dgrissom.com/dimwit/?R2,5,6,9,[1-7]%7D5,2,9,6,-1%7D)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>46</s> 27 bytes

```c
f(i){i="BAGAADKAJH"[i]-66;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOtNWycnR3dHRxdvRy0MpOjNW18zMuvZ/bmJmnoZmNVdBUWZeSZqGkmpKTJ6STpqGgaamNYagITZBI2yCxtgETbAJmmITNMMmaI5N0AKboCVIsPY/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
6 8u9yuu5u0K$i
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?header=&code=6%208u9yuu5u0K%24i&footer=&input=5&flags=)

```
¿£Ṣƥ*ðdiṅ×Ɗ€¿i
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?header=&code=%C2%BF%C2%A3%E1%B9%A2%C6%A5*%C3%B0di%E1%B9%85%C3%97%C6%8A%E2%82%AC%C2%BFi&footer=&input=5&flags=)

##### Explanation

```python
6 8u9yuu5u0K$i  # Implicit input
6 8u9yuu5u0     # Push 6,8,-1,9,2,-1,-1,5,-1,0
           K    # Wrap the stack (reversed)
            $i  # Index the input in
                # Implicit output
```

```python
¿£Ṣƥ*ðdiṅ×Ɗ€¿i  # Implicit input
¿£Ṣƥ*ðdiṅ×Ɗ€¿   # Push compressed list
                # [0,-1,5,-1,-1,2,9,-1,8,6]
             i  # Index the input in
                # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 18 bytes

```
_1".{&'0x5xx29x86'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxKd5QSa9aTd2gwrSiwsiywsJMHSqhyZWanJGvoKGjl6apZpepZ2gAkViwAEIDAA)

```
_1".{&'0x5xx29x86'
    {&'0x5xx29x86'  NB. index into a string literal
_1".                NB. eval the result using _1 as a default value
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

```javascript
x=>'0x'+'106003a097'[x]-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/wtZO3aBCXVvd0MDMwMA40cDSXD26IlbX8P9/AA)