# Find the Cross Product

Tags: code-golf, math, linear-algebra

The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two three-dimensional vectors \$\vec a\$ and \$\vec b\$ is the unique vector \$\vec c\$ such that:

- ﻿\$\vec c\$ is orthogonal to both \$\vec a\$ and \$\vec b\$
- The magnitude of \$\vec c\$ is equal to the area of the parallelogram formed by \$\vec a\$ and \$\vec b\$
- The directions of \$\vec a\$, \$\vec b\$, and \$\vec c\$, in that order, follow the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

There are a few equivalent formulas for cross product, but one is as follows:

$$\vec a\times\vec b=\det\begin{bmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

where \$\vec i\$, \$\vec j\$, and \$\vec k\$ are the unit vectors in the first, second, and third dimensions.

#### Challenge

Given two 3D vectors, write a full program or function to find their cross product. Builtins that specifically calculate the cross product are disallowed.

#### Input

Two arrays of three real numbers each. If your language doesn't have arrays, the numbers still must be grouped into threes. Both vectors will have magnitude \$<2^{16}\$. Note that the cross product is noncommutative (\$\vec a\times\vec b=-\bigl(\vec b\times\vec a\bigr)\$), so you should have a way to specify order.

#### Output

Their cross product, in a reasonable format, with each component accurate to four significant figures or \$10^{-4}\$, whichever is looser. Scientific notation is optional.

#### Test cases

```
[3, 1, 4], [1, 5, 9]
[-11, -23, 14]

[5, 0, -3], [-3, -2, -8]
[-6, 49, -10]

[0.95972, 0.25833, 0.22140],[0.93507, -0.80917, -0.99177]
[-0.077054, 1.158846, -1.018133]

[1024.28, -2316.39, 2567.14], [-2290.77, 1941.87, 712.09]
[-6.6345e+06, -6.6101e+06, -3.3173e+06]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

<sub>Maltysen posted a [similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70269/39328), but the response was poor and the question wasn't edited.</sub>

Comment: Can the input be taken as a 2D array?

Comment: Yes, as long as 2 is the outer dimension.

Answer (score 16):

## Jelly, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
;"s€2U×¥/ḅ-U
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OyJz4oKsMlXDl8KlL-G4hS1V&input=&args=WzMsIDEsIDRdLCBbMSwgNSwgOV0)

#### How it works

```
;"s€2U×¥/ḅ-U Main link. Input: [a1, a2, a3], [b1, b2, b3]

;"           Concatenate each [x1, x2, x3] with itself.
             Yields [a1, a2, a3, a1, a2, a3], [b1, b2, b3, b1, b2, b3].
  s€2        Split each array into pairs.
             Yields [[a1, a2], [a3, a1], [a2, a3]], [[b1, b2], [b3, b1], [b2, b3]].
       ¥     Define a dyadic chain:
     U         Reverse the order of all arrays in the left argument.
      ×        Multiply both arguments, element by element.
        /    Reduce the 2D array of pairs by this chain.
             Reversing yields [a2, a1], [a1, a3], [a3, a2].
             Reducing yields [a2b1, a1b2], [a1b3, a3b1], [a3b2, a2b3].
         ḅ-  Convert each pair from base -1 to integer.
             This yields [a1b2 - a2b1, a3b1 - a1b3, a2b3 - a3b2]
           U Reverse the array.
             This yields [a2b3 - a3b2, a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1] (cross product).
```

### Non-competing version (10 bytes)

OK, this is embarrassing, but the array manipulation language Jelly did not have a built-in for array rotation until just now. With this new built-in, we can save two additional bytes.

```
ṙ-×
ç_ç@ṙ-
```

This uses the approach from [@AlexA.'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70517). [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmZLcOXCsOnX8OnQOG5mS0&input=&args=WzMsIDEsIDRd+WzEsIDUsIDld)

#### How it works

```
ṙ-×     Helper link. Left input: x = [x1, x2, x3]. Right input: y = [y1, y2, y3].

ṙ-      Rotate x 1 unit to the right (actually, -1 units to the left).
        This yields [x3, x1, x2].
  ×     Multiply the result with y.
        This yields [x3y1, x1y2, x2y3].


ç_ç@ṙ-  Main link. Left input: a = [a1, a2, a3]. Right input: b = [b1, b2, b3].

ç       Call the helper link with arguments a and b.
        This yields [a3b1, a1b2, a2b3].
  ç@    Call the helper link with arguments b and a.
        This yields [b3a1, b1a2, b2a3].
_       Subtract the result to the right from the result to the left.
        This yields [a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1, a2b3 - a3b2].
    ṙ-  Rotate the result 1 unit to the right.
        This yields [a2b3 - a3b2, a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1] (cross product).
```

Comment: Convert each pair from base -1? That's just evil. +1

Answer (score 11):

### **LISP, <strike>128</strike> 122 bytes**

Hi! This is my code:

```
(defmacro D(x y)`(list(*(cadr,x)(caddr,y))(*(caddr,x)(car,y))(*(car,x)(cadr,y))))(defun c(a b)(mapcar #'- (D a b)(D b a)))
```

I know that it isn't the shortest solution, but nobody has provided one in Lisp, until now :)

Copy and paste the following code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/try_lisp.php) to try it!

```
(defmacro D(x y)`(list(*(cadr,x)(caddr,y))(*(caddr,x)(car,y))(*(car,x)(cadr,y))))(defun c(a b)(mapcar #'- (D a b)(D b a)))

(format T "Inputs: (3 1 4), (1 5 9)~%")
(format T "Result ~S~%~%" (c '(3 1 4) '(1 5 9)))

(format T "Inputs: (5 0 -3), (-3 -2 -8)~%")
(format T "Result ~S~%~%" (c '(5 0 -3) '(-3 -2 -8)))

(format T "Inputs: (0.95972 0.25833 0.22140), (0.93507 -0.80917 -0.99177)~%")
(format T "Result ~S~%" (c '(0.95972 0.25833 0.22140) '(0.93507 -0.80917 -0.99177)))

(format T "Inputs: (1024.28 -2316.39 2567.14), (-2290.77 1941.87 712.09)~%")
(format T "Result ~S~%" (c '(1024.28 -2316.39 2567.14) '(-2290.77 1941.87 712.09)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. This is a great answer, +1. Well done for answering in a language that isn't going to win, but still golfing it down loads. Often [tag:code-golf] challenges are more about within languages than between them!

Answer (score 10):

## J, <s>27</s> 14 bytes

```
2|.v~-v=.*2&|.
```

This is a dyadic verb that accepts arrays on the left and right and returns their cross product.

Explanation:

```
         *2&|.     NB. Dyadic verb: Left input * twice-rotated right input
      v=.          NB. Locally assign to v
   v~-             NB. Commute arguments, negate left
2|.                NB. Left rotate twice
```

Example:

```
    f =: 2|.v~-v=.*2&|.
    3 1 4 f 1 5 9
_11 _23 14
```

[Try it here](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=f%20%3D%3A%202%7C.v~-v%3D.*2%26%7C.)

Saved 13 bytes thanks to randomra!

Comment: @randomra That's awesome, thanks! I'm no J expert so I'm still figuring out how exactly it works but I have a general idea.

Comment: Some clarifications: `*2&|.` is a fork of two verbs: `*` and `2&|.`. It multiplies the left input by a rotated by 2 right input. This fork is stored in `v` so when we write `v~`, it is equivalent to `(*2&|.)~`, where the `~` swaps the left and right input parameters for the parenthesized part.

Comment: @randomra Okay, that makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

## Dyalog APL, 12 bytes

```
2⌽p⍨-p←⊣×2⌽⊢
```

Based on [@AlexA.'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70517) and (coincidentally) equivalent to @randomra's improvement in that answer's comment section.

Try it online on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=3%201%204%20%28%202%u233Dp%u2368-p%u2190%u22A3%D72%u233D%u22A2%20%29%201%205%209&run).

#### How it works

```
2⌽p⍨-p←⊣×2⌽⊢  Dyadic function.
              Left argument: a = [a1, a2, a3]. Right argument: b = [b1, b2, b3].

         2⌽⊢  Rotate b 2 units to the left. Yields [b3, b1, b2].
       ⊣×     Multiply the result by a. Yields [a1b3, a2b1, a3b2].
     p←       Save the tacit function to the right (NOT the result) in p.
  p⍨          Apply p to b and a (reversed). Yields [b1a3, b2a1, b3a2].
    -         Subtract the right result (p) from the left one (p⍨).
              This yields [a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1, a2b3 - a3b2].
2⌽            Rotate the result 2 units to the left.
              This yields [a2b3 - a3b2, a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1].
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, <strike>156</strike> <strike>154</strike> <strike>150</strike> <strike>148</strike> 144 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){float v[6];int i=7,j,k;for(;--i;)scanf("%f",v+6-i);for(i=1;i<4;)j=i%3,k=++i%3,printf("%f ",v[j]*v[k+3]-v[k]*v[j+3]);}
```

Not going to be winning any prizes for length, but thought I'd have a go anyway.

- Input is a newline- or space-delimited list of components (i.e. a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3), output is space-delimited (i.e. c1 c2 c3).
- Cyclically permutes the indices of the two input vectors to calculate the product - takes fewer characters than writing out the determinants!

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/5acf)

Ungolfed:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    float v[6];
    int i = 7, j, k;
    for (; --i; ) scanf("%f", v + 6 - 1);
    for (i = 1; i < 4; )
        j = i % 3,
        k = ++i % 3,
        printf("%f ", v[j] * v[k + 3] - v[k] * v[j + 3]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. This is a great answer; well done for answering in a language that won't beat the golfing languages. +1.

Comment: Your first `for` doesn't need `{}`

Comment: cheers, updated.

Comment: You can replace &v[6-i] with v+6-i. Also, you can replace semicolon after j=i%3 and k=(i+1)%3 with commas, which makes everything after the for a single statement so you can omit the {}. Finally,  if you initialise i to 1 for the second for loop, you can move the increment into k=++i%3 saving a couple of brackets.  If you're not worried about warnings and use the right version of C, you can skip the include as well.

Comment: awesome, cheers! My compiler won't accept the omission of the header, so I've stuck with a version I'm able to build.

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcnRCsIgFMbxV5HBQHPnIqxFnHwS8UIE42i5sYY3sb26WV18fH/4ebh7Xyvpy5Dw6SjzKN7hMbmVFTNaDNPCEYBQvLzLgXd96IYiRyDxN5LypnBeKK8/ZY1N1NQreygmSWWh3bdjayGShr0hbrUqdmSntjO7fgA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 41 bytes

```haskell
x(a,b,c)(d,e,f)=(b*f-c*e,c*d-a*f,a*e-b*d)
```

A straightforward solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 51

```
eval set {$1}*{$2}
bc<<<"scale=4;$6-$8;$7-$3;$2-$4"
```

- Line 1 constructs a brace expansion that gives the cartesian product of the two vectors and sets them into the positional parameters.
- Line 2 subtracts the appropriate terms; `bc` does the arithmetic evaluation to the required precision.

Input is as two comma-separated lists on the command-line.  Output as newline-separated lines:

```
$ ./crossprod.sh 0.95972,0.25833,0.22140 0.93507,-0.80917,-0.99177
-.07705
1.15884
-1.01812
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 17 bytes

```
!*[6,7,2;8,3,4])d
```

First input is **a**, second is **b**.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ISpbNiw3LDI7OCwzLDRdKWQ&input=WzAuOTU5NzIsIDAuMjU4MzMsIDAuMjIxNDBdClswLjkzNTA3LCAtMC44MDkxNywgLTAuOTkxNzddCg)

#### Explanation

```
!              % input b as a row array and transpose into a column array
*              % input a as a row array. Compute 3x3 matrix of pairwise products
[6,7,2;8,3,4]  % 2x3 matrix that picks elements from the former in column-major order
)              % apply index
d              % difference within each column
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
-VF*VM.<VLQ_BMS2
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-VF*VM.%3CVLQ_BMS2&input=[3%2C+1%2C+4]%2C+[1%2C+5%2C+9]&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
-VF*VM.<VLQ_BMS2   Q = input, pair of vectors [u, v]
              S2   creates the list [1, 2]
           _BM     transforms it to [[1, -1], [2, -2]]
      .<VLQ        rotate of the input vectors accordingly to the left:
                   [[u by 1, v by -1], [u by 2, v by -2]]
   *VM             vectorized multiplication for each of the vector-pairs
-VF                vectorized subtraction of the resulting two vectors
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

Takes input in the form \$[[x_1,x_2],[y_1,y_2],[z_1,z_2]]\$. If you want them to be two lists of x-y-z coordinates, just prepend `Z` to the beginning of the program.

```
ṁ4ÆḊƝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkaTw20Pd3Qdm/v/cPujpjXu//9HR0frGuooGMbqKEQDaSMQrWuso6BrGQtigsRMQAwjqBqglGlsbCwA)

Here is a PDF [explanation](https://mr-xcoder.github.io/data/Cross_Product_Calculation.pdf) in case SE markdown can't handle it.

---

#### The cross-product in analytic form

Let \$(x_1,y_1,z_1)\$ be the coordinates of \$\vec{v_1}\$ and \$(x_2,y_2,z_2)\$ be the coordinates of \$\vec{v_2}\$. Their analytic expressions are as follows:

$$\boldsymbol{\vec{v_1}}=x_1\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}+y_1\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}+z_1\cdot\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\vec{v_2}}=x_2\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}+y_2\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}+z_2\cdot\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}$$

The only thing left to do now is to also write their cross-product in terms of its coordinates in the \$Oxyz\$ space.

$$\boldsymbol{\vec{v_1}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{v_2}}=\left(x_1\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}+y_1\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}+z_1\cdot\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}\right)\times\left(x_2\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}+y_2\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}+z_2\cdot\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}\right)$$

Keeping in mind that: $$\boldsymbol{\vec{i}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}=\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}, \:\: \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{k}}=-\boldsymbol{\vec{j}},  \:\: \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}=-\boldsymbol{\vec{k}}, \:\: \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{k}}=\boldsymbol{\vec{i}}, \:\: \boldsymbol{\vec{k}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}=\boldsymbol{\vec{j}}, \:\:  \boldsymbol{\vec{k}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}=-\boldsymbol{\vec{i}}$$

After the necessary rearrangements and calculations:

$$\boldsymbol{\vec{v_1}}\times \boldsymbol{\vec{v_2}}=(y_1z_2-z_1y_2)\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{i}}+(z_1x_2-x_1z_2)\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{j}}+(x_1y_2-y_1x_2)\cdot \boldsymbol{\vec{k}}$$

#### The close relationship with matrix determinants

There's an interesting thing to note here:

$$x_1y_2-y_1x_2=\left|\begin{matrix}x_1 & y_1 \\\ x_2 & y_2\end{matrix}\right|$$
$$z_1x_2-x_1z_2=\left|\begin{matrix}z_1 & x_1 \\\ z_2 & x_2\end{matrix}\right|$$
$$y_1z_2-z_1y_2=\left|\begin{matrix}y_1 & z_1 \\\ y_2 & z_2\end{matrix}\right|$$

Where we use the notation \$\left|\cdot\right|\$ for matrix determinant. Notice the *beautiful* rotational symmetry?

#### Jelly code explanation

Well... not much to explain here. It just generates the matrix:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & x_1 \\\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & x_2\end{matrix}\right)$$

And for each pair of neighbouring matrices, it computes the determinant of the matrix formed by joining the two.

```
ṁ4ÆḊƝ – Monadic Link. Takes input as [[x1,x2],[y1,y2],[z1,z2]].
ṁ4    – Mold 4. Cycle the list up to length 4, reusing the elements if necessary.
        Generates [[x1,x2],[y1,y2],[z1,z2],[x1,x2]].
    Ɲ – For each pair of neighbours: [[x1,x2],[y1,y2]], [[y1,y2],[z1,z2]], [[z1,z2],[x1,x2]].
  ÆḊ  – Compute the determinant of those 2 paired together into a single matrix.
```

Comment: [neater form in the equations here :P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>73</s> 48 bytes

Thanks @FryAmTheEggman

```
lambda (a,b,c),(d,e,f):[b*f-c*e,c*d-a*f,a*e-b*d]
```

This is based on the component definition of the vector cross product.

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/Pt0NpE)

Comment: `lambda (a,b,c),(d,e,f):...` should save a lot.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman You are right. I forgot that lambda can specify how the argument should be.

Answer (score 3):

## K5, <s>44</s> <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 32 bytes

Wrote this one quite a while ago and [dusted it off again recently](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/ike/examples/vector.k#L16).

```
{{x[y]-x[|y]}[*/x@']'3 3\'5 6 1}
```

In action:

```
 cross: {{x[y]-x[|y]}[*/x@']'3 3\'5 6 1};

 cross (3 1 4;1 5 9)
-11 -23 14
 cross (0.95972 0.25833 0.22140;0.93507 -0.80917 -0.99177)
-7.705371e-2 1.158846 -1.018133
```

### Edit 1:

Saved 4 bytes by taking input as a list of lists instead of two separate arguments:

```
old: {m:{*/x@'y}(x;y);{m[x]-m[|x]}'(1 2;2 0;0 1)}
new: {m:{*/x@'y}x    ;{m[x]-m[|x]}'(1 2;2 0;0 1)}
```

### Edit 2:

Saved 3 bytes by computing a lookup table with base-decode:

```
old: {m:{*/x@'y}x;{m[x]-m[|x]}'(1 2;2 0;0 1)}
new: {m:{*/x@'y}x;{m[x]-m[|x]}'3 3\'5 6 1}
```

### Edit 3:

Save 5 bytes by rearranging application to permit using a tacit definition instead of a local lambda. Unfortunately, this solution no longer works in oK, and requires the official k5 interpreter. Gonna have to take my word for this one until I fix the bug in oK:

```
old: {m:{*/x@'y}x;{m[x]-m[|x]}'3 3\'5 6 1}
new: {{x[y]-x[|y]}[*/x@']     '3 3\'5 6 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
->u,v{(0..2).map{|a|u[a-2]*v[a-1]-u[a-1]*v[a-2]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU4xCsMwDNzzCo9tsYUk27U9tB8xHtIhWyEUHChJ3u4qLmQQd6fTifvU17dNj2aeVS/rBQH4Cu9xXrdxq3k0XG6LABVTO3TFZd/brKacrVaklStaZUGvVSplGLolArUy9vCM3BmWiaeNkHwKskNgH63thMlh0YdnPQa5R4iY6M@SkHDmCdkBx@OvpTvYpBX7ewDqZQxzQggSpOQIopBADCj12g8)

Returning after 2 years, I shaved off 12 bytes by using how Ruby treats negative array indices. `-1` is the last element of the array, `-2` the second last etc.

## Ruby, 57

```ruby
->u,v{(0..2).map{|a|u[b=(a+1)%3]*v[c=(a+2)%3]-u[c]*v[b]}}
```

**In test program**

```ruby
f=->u,v{(0..2).map{|a|u[b=(a+1)%3]*v[c=(a+2)%3]-u[c]*v[b]}}

p f[[3, 1, 4], [1, 5, 9]]

p f[[5, 0, -3], [-3, -2, -8]]

p f[[0.95972, 0.25833, 0.22140],[0.93507, -0.80917, -0.99177]]

p f[[1024.28, -2316.39, 2567.14], [-2290.77, 1941.87, 712.09]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>38 33 25</s> 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Det@{a={i,j,},##}~D~{a}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xisMwDIZfRRDoJAtJjmt76JGhD9C9dDCl5XLQG45swn31nNIMQp/@XxL/qy3fj1db5ntbn3CC9fxYJmsnm/EHOw5Df5/f1vphvfzNv8vVXIHwBc/rMNxucIBpmsDMIoIgjB3BvCeE2jc2J0YIcRuCLwX1KrvHVFPNLjBpKjF@QGXkjpsXE2dfZipcZafqkPdjYR1Jy/YxypFiRdB0zCSfDEG1MmW/kjoKFYcsSuyp@voP)

Comment: Surprised there be no builtin in Mathematica for this

Comment: @Seggan The builtin is `Cross`. But this challenge says that builtins that specifically calculate the cross product are disallowed.

Comment: -1 with `Null` as one of the units

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 40 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d,e,f)=>[b*f-c*e,c*d-a*f,a*e-b*d]
```

44 bytes if the input needs to be two arrays:

```
([a,b,c],[d,e,f])=>[b*f-c*e,c*d-a*f,a*e-b*d]
```

52 bytes for a more interesting version:

```
(a,b)=>a.map((_,i)=>a[x=++i%3]*b[y=++i%3]-a[y]*b[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```julia
f(a,b)=1:3 .|>i->det([eye(3)[i,:] a b])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NagMxDIX3OYWWNshCP@PYDjQXGbyY0AlMCCGEdFHo3aeadFOyEPrQe5Le5eu6TGVdz2HCU/yQgwH9HJd0/JyfYZy/52BxXPDQYYJTj@v9sdye11s4h9EQBGHoCKP3jNB6jLt/Bh8xQrLNkdyd1Ku@mZhabsUVJs3V7AUqA3fcNMtcfIupcpM/ag7l7YqwDqR1@2GyJ2sImveF5BUvqTam4uvSBqHqUESJt8DrLw)

Uses the determinant-based formula given in the task description.

Thanks to H.PWiz for -6 bytes.

Comment: 39 bytes with two tricks: `f(a,b)=1:3 .|>i->det([eye(3)[i,:] a b])`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 41 bytes

```
(a,b)->Vec(matdet(Mat([[x^2,x,1],a,b]~)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BagMxDEWvIrKyQTaSPI7tRXODbrsxU3DTpASmxYRZpJtefSpnFkJP@v8L9Xa/ua@@XeEFNtPww7rT2@Vsvtv6eVnNa1tNrY93wQfyjKrPf9barfW@/JoG7gT9fvtZFQ9jOMC5LYu5IjRrsdYaEBhhmhGq9ohQ5sFViRBcGINTkxOtvGvkSyxJF@Ql5hCeIDzRUFUMkZK6yWcqvFNRSHuaSSYveZwMfPShIEg8Js/PJ5xIIZ80xWVinxUSiyd9a7bbPw)

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 62 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [@MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)
-9 bytes using `Ans` instead of `Prompt`  and `Disp`

Not 62 characters -- TI-BASIC is tokenized.

```
:Prompt A
:{Ans(2)ʟA(3)-Ans(3)ʟA(2),Ans(3)ʟA(1)-Ans(1)ʟA(3),Ans(1)ʟA(2)-Ans(2)ʟA(1
```

Usage example, computing \$\langle 1,2,3\rangle\times\langle 0,1,0\rangle\$:

```
{1,2,3}:pgrmXPROD
A=?{0,1,0}
                  {⁻3 0 1}
```

Comment: you don't need to close parentheses, you can remove the last 2 characters

Comment: I think you can golf two more bytes by using `ʟA` and `ʟB` [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143898/98541)

Comment: @MarcMush I didn't know about that! I didn't use named lists when I first wrote it because I wanted to use a list I could guarantee actually existed, but I'll have to test that and update this if it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.5.0.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.5.0.2), 306 bytes

```
func a:
dup
dup
ldelem 0
pop $3
ldelem 1
pop $4
ldelem 2
pop $5
dup
dup
ldelem 0
pop $a
ldelem 1
pop $1
ldelem 2
pop $2
push $1
push $5
mul
push $2
push $4
mul
sub
push $2
push $3
mul
push $a
push $5
mul
sub
push $a
push $4
mul
push $1
push $3
mul
sub
push 3
newarr f32
pop $a
push $a
swap
stelem 2
push $a
swap
stelem 1
push $a
swap
stelem 0
push $a
ret
end
```

The function `a` expects two `~arr:f32` arrays representing the two 3D vectors on the stack before calling it.
\$\vec a\$ should be pushed to the stack first, then \$\vec b\$ should be pushed.
This function leaves an `~arr:f32` array on the stack which corresponds to \$\vec c\$.

**Explanation:**

```
; Input: two ~arr:f32 representing the two vectors
func a:
    ; stack: [ a, b, c ], [ d, e, f ]
    ; These numbers represent the coordinates of the two vectors for an easier explanation

    ; Duplicate the second vector twice
    dup
    dup

    ; stack: [ a, b, c ], [ d, e, f ], [ d, e, f ], [ d, e, f ]
    ; Store the elements in the array to the pre-defined registers $3, $4 and $5
    ldelem 0
    pop $3
    ldelem 1
    pop $4
    ldelem 2
    pop $5

    ; Duplicate the first vector twice
    dup
    dup

    ; stack: [ a, b, c ], [ a, b, c ], [ a, b, c ]
    ; Store the elements in the array to the pre-defined registers $a, $1 and $2
    ldelem 0
    pop $a
    ldelem 1
    pop $1
    ldelem 2
    pop $2

    ; Perform the algorithm: [ bf - ce, cd - af, ae - bd ]
    ; $a = a, $1 = b, $2 = c
    ; $3 = d, $4 = e, $5 = f

    ; bf - ce
    push $1
    push $5
    mul
    push $2
    push $4
    mul
    sub

    ; cd - af
    push $2
    push $3
    mul
    push $a
    push $5
    mul
    sub

    ; ae - bd
    push $a
    push $4
    mul
    push $1
    push $3
    mul
    sub

    ; Create the result array and store it in $a
    push 3
    newarr f32
    pop $a

    ; Store the resulting values from earlier into this new array
    ; "swap" swaps the top two values on the stack
    push $a
    swap
    stelem 2

    push $a
    swap
    stelem 1
    
    push $a
    swap
    stelem 0

    push $a
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/Octave, 61 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NasMwEITvfQodbVgv@yNFEiKQ9zA@SE0CPbWQ0Nd3VwoB04NgdjTzSfv9@ay/t32/ny9ThTav19tzWhkIqNTSthmGQcD/DbNexlb2yu7sVgXH4PxWXBuzDQFctvn69fiZ7lM1p/E8l48qPWC3BG7R3hjGYohF7KRDyeYmo6Q9Q5hDjmYSSkiqQwh76pR3QgNFwxAmyvxS2UQ8YK3YdGD9@CyJR0n9feUTagYn4RSRxz4jsohkwmg4zp4xmYgsSMcNvVG9Ufc/)

```matlab
f=@(a,b)[det([1,0,0;a;b]),det([0,1,0;a;b]),det([0,0,1;a;b])];
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
D/@HodgeDual[1##]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4/zsIwDMWvYqkSU2JspyHJAOrAwMheMVT8@5A@QEJlinIGDsAhOUJx6WD55/ds6127/u947frLvhtOsIRhPW8298P5uH52/y1/Xu@q2s2G7eNy69tcVQXsCk6tijuYQdM0kHN2BthAXQxk7d5AKiNnJTJg3ThYXbKiFSePMPkUVCAUH537gXBNxYye8xR0mTBS4omSQpiOmaRGieNHxwt0yYD4RUD@ZbAiiTDoFaeaMSoEFiRNVYYv)

`` is `\[TensorWedge]` (U+F3DB).

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 23 chars, 46 bytes

```
{((1⌽⍺)×5⌽⍵)-(5⌽⍺)×1⌽⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{((1⌽⍺)×5⌽⍵)-(5⌽⍺)×1⌽⍵}
  (3 1 4) f (1 5 9)
¯11 ¯23 14 
  (5 0 ¯3) f (¯3 ¯2 ¯8)
¯6 49 ¯10 
  (0.95972 0.25833 0.22140) f (0.93507 ¯0.80917 ¯0.99177)
¯0.0770537061 1.158846002 ¯1.018133265 
  (1024.28 ¯2316.39 2567.14) f (¯2290.77 1941.87 712.09)
¯6634530.307 ¯6610106.843 ¯3317298.117
```