# Index and return 3 characters

Tags: code-golf, string, number, arithmetic, alphabet

The challenge is simple: Read 3 letters from a system input¹ and convert them to numbers (`A-1, B-2, C-3...Z-26`)². Print each of those numbers in the order the letters were inputted in, each on a new line and then the sum of all 3 numbers, on its own line as well.

NOTE: There will be no extra input characters, only 3 letters. However, the code must be case insensitive.

This follows the standard rules of code golf, and the shortest byte count wins.

¹If your language does not support input, you may use from a file, or predefined variable instead. However, the program should be able to run any and all possibilities.

²The program should be able to take lowercase AND uppercase, and allow for a mix of lowercase and uppercase (e.g `wOq` or `ZNu`)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. I'd suggest using our [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) rather than specifying your own.

Comment: I will check it out. It's a pretty simple question, but I thought it might be a fun little challenge to solve if you dont have a ton of time for something more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `so`, 4 bytes

```
øA⟑,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzbyIsIiIsIsO4QeKfkSwiLCIiLCJaTnUiXQ==)

Inspired by a -1 from @TheThunno

### Explained

```
øA⟑,
øA    # Char to alphabet index
  ⟑,  # print each on newlines
      # the s flag sums the list and the o flag prints it even though implicit output gets disabled from the map
```

Comment: Impressive. I still don't understand how people learn these languages. I don't understand any part of what it does, just that it works 

Comment: @WiredUpDIY I mean, the fact that I created Vyxal probably has something to do with the fact that I know it well . Learning a golfing language takes time and practice as one would need to spend if they were learning a practical language

Comment: @wiredupdiy actually, Vyxal's pretty easy to understand (It's one of the few I understood), it was designed to be understandable and relatable to practical languages too.

Comment: [6 bytes lol get golfd](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=KJ&code=32%25%E2%82%8C%E2%81%8B%E2%88%91&inputs=aBc&header=&footer=)

Comment: [5 bytes with only one flag lol :p](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw7hBOuKIkUoiLCIiLCJhQmMiXQ==)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O%32Ṅ€S
```

A full program that accepts a string of three letters and prints their alphabetic indices followed by their sum on four lines.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f1djo4c6WR01rgv///@@ekwYA)**

#### How?

```
O%32Ṅ€S - Main Link: list of characters, C
O       - cast to ordinals  A:65 ... Z:90 / a:97 ... z:122
 %32    - modulo 32         A:1  ... Z:26 / a:1  ... z:26
    Ṅ€  - print each followed by a new line
      S - sum
        - implicit print
```

---

9 if it  had to be the *first* three of a string of letters ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsXG/qrGRg93tjxqWhP8//9/x6Rkl9Q094xMAA)):

```
ḣ3O%32Ṅ€S
```

...or 12 if it had to both handle non-alphabetic characters, and take the *first* three *letters* ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//ZsOY4bqg4bijM08lMzLhuYTigqxT////P0EhKmIuLi5jO2QrZT1B)):

```
fØẠḣ3O%32Ṅ€S
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `combinators.extras`, <sup><s>42</s></sup> 35 bytes

```
0 [ read1 32 mod dup . + ] thrice .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg9DsIwDAbQq3w7UgR0gwNULO2AOiEGk7iqRfODY0Q5feCNbyZvWdt0vQz9CVS9CHyOD0n0/@p4M6UKyXiyJl4RyRYUZbNvUUmGc9vjBmUKB3RHxBwQ3gUOO9xhi4pnuNY@4@sH)

*-7 bytes thanks to @MarcMush*

- `0` Push `0`, our sum, to the data stack.
- `[ ... ] thrice` Call a quotation three times.
- `read1` Read one code point from standard input.
- `32 mod` Modulo 32.
- `dup .` Output on its own line non-destructively.
- `+` Add it to the sum.
- `.` Print the sum.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcg9DsIwDAbQq3w7UgR0gwNULO2AOiEGk7iqRfODY0Q5feCNbyZvWdt0vQz9CVS9CHyOD0n0/@p4M6UKyXiyJl4RyRYUZbNvUUmGc9vjBmUKB3RHxBwQ3gUOO9xhi4pnuNY@4@sH "Factor – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, <s>56</s> 53

Ending parens discounted.

- Input is in A1
- B1

```
=ArrayFormula(-64+CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,{1;2;3},1))))
or
=ArrayFormula(-9+DECIMAL(MID(A1,{1;2;3},1),36))
```

- C1

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Comment: Creative! I like your unorthodox method! Have an upvote!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 10 bytes

Full program. Prompts via stdin and prints to stdout

```apl
+⌿⎕←⍪⎕A⍳⌈⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/2o579j/qmPmqb8Kh3FZDh@Kh386Oejke980Dy/xXAoICr3L@QS1dXlwvGj/IrBQA)

`⍞` prompt via stdin

`⌈` uppercase

`⎕A⍳` **i**ndices in uppercase **A**lphabet

`⍪` make into column

`⎕←` send to stdout

`+⌿`‌ sum (and implicitly print to stdout)

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```elixir
&(IO.puts Enum.reduce &1,0,fn b,c->IO.puts b=b-(b>91&&96||64)
c+b
end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p9m@19Nw9Nfr6C0pFjBNa80V68oNaU0OVVBzVDHQCctTyFJJ1nXDqYgyTZJVyPJztJQTc3SrKbGzESTK1k7iSs1L0Xzf5qehnpUXqm65v//AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pF`, 27 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [@Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!

```perl
$\+=$;*say$;=31&ord for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWxVqrOLFSxdrW2FAtvyhFIS2/yMGttvr//6i80n/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL3P7r@prqGRroGQAA)

Comment: Nice! Seeing it I'm sure I've seen that method in the last, but it never sticks! Thank you @Sisyphus!

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, <strike>135</strike> 132 bytes (on-calc) / <strike>145</strike> 135 bytes (as text)

-3 bytes thanks to MarcMush!

```
Input Str1
For(I,1,3
int(.5inString(" AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz",sub(Str1,I,1
Disp Ans
A+Ans→A
End
A
```

### Explanation

- `Input Str1`: Take text input into string variable `Str1`.
- `For(I,1,3`: Start a for-loop with variable I from 1 to 3 (TI-BASIC strings and lists are 1-indexed).
- `int(.5inString(" AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz",sub(Str1,I,1`: Find the position of the current character of `Str1` in the alphabet string, divide it by 2 and find the floor of it to get the number of the uppercase or lowercase letter. Parentheses at the end of a line in TI-BASIC don't need to be closed, so using `.5` in front of `inString(` rather than `/2` behind it saves a couple bytes' worth of parentheses.
- `Disp Ans`: Display what the previous line returned (`Ans`).
- `A+Ans→A`: Add `Ans` to the sum (`Disp` doesn't return anything so `Ans` remains the same).
- `End`: End of `For(` loop.
- `A`: Implicitly print the sum (variable `A`) at the end of the program.

Comment: nice first answer! you can save 3 bytes (I think) by [removing your first line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52967/98541)

Comment: @MarcMush oh cool, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 53 bytes

*-10 bytes by dingledooper*

```python
i=[ord(c)%32for c in input()]
*map(print,i+[sum(i)]),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2Or8oRSNZU9XYKC2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0Y7m0chMLNAqKMvNKdDK1o4tLczUyNWM1df7/L/cvBAA)

Comment: Thats pretty much as condensed as python can get because it needs so much formatting. +1 

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2Or8oRSNZU9XYKC2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0Y7m0chMLNAqKMvNKdDK1o4tLczUyNWM1df7/L/cvBAA) is the best I could do. Still quite verbose, but that's Python for you.

Comment: that map trick is nasty :)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 38 bytes

```
+++++++++++++>+++[>,.<<.>>[->+<]<-]>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGxnYAXG0nY6ejY2enV20rp22TayNbqydnd7//@VGxgA)

### Explanation:

The first 13 plus signs put the 'newline' character into cell 0. Then, I initialize cell 1 as a counter with a value of 3. Then there's the main loop. This loop will get a character in cell 2, display it, display the 'newline' character in cell 0, add cell 2 to cell 3, which holds the running sum, and repeat until cell 1 has a value of zero. When the loop is done, it displays the value in cell 3, which, if you've been following, holds the running sum of the characters. However, there is a problem with this last part: it displays the sum of the three characters as an ascii character, not an integer. I don't know if this is actually an issue since I technically displayed the sum, but just in case, I added a (long) routine to the end of the code that displays the sum as an integer.

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 242 bytes

```
+++++++++++++>+++[>,.<<.>>[->+<]<-]>>+>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5JCoAwDHxQbF8wzEdCDlUQRPAg@P6a1PWggYY0s2T6tUzLuA1zrfIu@lN2GcikJgoMyUghHxIQCJPG2qiiCeJD/NDKQuztLXLNv8IOvp6CgK9EBk/jwYJh0OYDu3j3BbfIjYFPC4cidlxFraUfdg)

But wait, there's more. The routine I used only supports displaying eight bit numbers. This means that if I input 'abc' into the program, it displays:

```
a
b
c
39
```

If you didn't catch it, the sum of the ascii values of 'a','b', and 'c' is not 39. However, it's equivalent if you add 255. This is because the value of the cell was only calculated to 8 bits by the routine I used. At this point, brainfuck had had its effect on my brain, and I didn't really feel like rewriting any more code in it. If I need to change my submission because of this issue or any other issue, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>5.5</s> 4.5 bytes

```
;.@%$32+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK6z1HFRVjI20IVyo6ILFUX6lECYA)

<s>Shorter than the Vyxal answer</s> not anymore but still doesn't cheat by storing information in flags. Nibbles is an awesome language.

```
;.@%$32+
 .       For each character
  @       in the input:
   %       Modulo
    $       the character
     32     by 32
;        Take the result
       + and append its sum
```

*-1 byte by borrowing the modulo 32 trick from other answers*

Comment: Shorter? You sure?

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ŒuO_64Ṅ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opFL/eDOThztbHjWtCf7//3@5fyEA)

Full program which takes a three-character string of letters as the first command line argument. [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kgqOTSv3jzUwe7mx51LQm@P//cv9CAA) to read from STDIN

### How it works

```
ŒuO_64Ṅ€S - Main link. Takes [a,b,c] (a string) on the left
Œu        - Convert to uppercase
  O       - Ordinal
   _64    - Subtract 64 (A -> 1, B - 2 etc.)
       €  - Over each:
      Ṅ   -   Print with a trailing newline
        S - Take the sum, and print implicitly
```

Comment: Looks good, however (I probably wasn't clear enough) the first 3 lines should be the numerical values of each letter.

Comment: @WiredUpDIY Updated

Comment: [-2 by masking the case bit out instead of uppercasing with the builtin, then masking the 64 out too](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99fzdjw4c6WR01rgv///1/uXwgA)

Comment: ...didn't notice Jonathan beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 20 bytes

```
0&(3|?84*%:.
,&+&)&.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQE3DuMbewkRL1UqPS0dNW01TTe///0SuJK5kAA)

Why....why did I do this to myself?

### Explained

```
0&
```

First of all, we put `0` into the register, because it is intialised as `None`. The register will be used to track the sum of the three letters.

```
(3|
```

Three times:

```
?84*%
```

Take the next letter and modulo its ASCII value by 32. This trick is stolen from Jonathan Allen's Jelly answer, so go upvote that too.

```
:.
,
```

Print the result of that modulo, followed by a newline (yes, newlines really do push newlines in Keg. This entire language is cursed, what did you expect?)

```
&+&
```

Push the value of the register, add the modulo'd index and then place that back in the register

```
)&.
```

Close the for loop and print the register raw.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 38 bytes

```
(Print@Column[y=LetterNumber@#];Tr@y)&
```

Doesn't seem to run in [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyOgKDOvxME5P6c0Ny@60tYntaQktcivNDcptchBOdY6pMihUlPtf3q0UlReqVIs138A), so here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

*And here is a superior 32-byte approach given by att in the comments:*

```
Print/@##@*+##&@@LetterNumber@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoM69E30FZ2UFLW1lZzcHBJ7WkJLXIrzQ3KbXIQVntf3q0UlReqVIs138A)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoM69E36FaWVlHW1m5Vs3BwSe1pCS1yK80Nym1yEFZ7X96tFJUXqlSLNd/AA)

Comment: @att  You should post that as a separate answer.  It's not a variant of my 38-byte answer; it's a different and superior approach.     Is my 30-byte alternative allowed under Code Golf rules?

Comment: The alternative is not one of the [default submission formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/81203).

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoM69E30FZ2UFLW1lZzcHBJ7WkJLXIrzQ3KbXIQVntf3q0UlReqVIs138A)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...[a,b,c]=[...x].map(z=>parseInt(z,36)-9),a+b+c].join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLCoAgEADQfSdRtNkEQQvbd4YQnMx@mCMZEV7e6K3egQ8me@3xrgPNriyqvKofAWBEOUmr1f9Xw4mRZdVHvJIbws2ybFped1yimITVcNAeTGWKpZDIO/C0soWZzXnDefkA)

```javascript
x=>[                   // Define a function taking a parameter x, returning an array of...
  ...                  // Iterating over...
    [a,b,c]=           // assign a, b and c to...
    [...x].map(z=>     // x mapped to...
      parseInt(z,36)-9 // parse as base36, -9 to get charcode
    ),                 
  a+b+c                // and the sum of all three
].join`\n`             // Joined by newline
```

The trick is that parseInt is case-insensitive, saving a lot of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 36 Bytes

```
p $*.map{|c|p c.downcase.ord-96}.sum
```

Comment: Nice answer. I've not seen args passed like this as a default before though, usually I'd expect to pass a whole string of three chars... Regardless, you can save a couple of bytes in your solution using `upcase...-64`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBRUsvN7Gguia5pkAhWa@0IDmxOFUvvyhF18ykVq@4NPf///9R//P@lwIA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBRUsvN7Gguia5pkAhWa8kPz5Tw9hMU9eyVq@4NPf///@J/53@JwMA "Ruby – Try It Online") (inspired by A username's JS answer)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBRUsvN7Gguia5pkAhWS@/KEXV2KhWr7g09////4n/nf4nAwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BFS6@4NLe6JrmmQCFZL78oRdXYqPb///@J/53@JwMA "Ruby – Try It Online"), though I'm not convinced this input format is legit (at a quick glance, I couldn't find it under our [default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/92901)). [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DFRi@psiS1WK@4NLe6JrmmQCFZ1dio9v//RKdkAA "Ruby – Try It Online") reading a string from STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
r=read(stdin).%32
println.([r;sum(r)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v8i2KDUxRaO4JCUzT1NP1diIq6AoM68kJ09PI7rIurg0V6NIM1bz//9Ep2QA)

Answer (score 2):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate) 0.84, <del>107</del> 77 bytes

This code expects 1 argument passed to the compiler, with the 3 characters used for input.

Outputs the text directly and doesn't return anything.

```
{@eachargv.0}{@callord intoZ _}{@set%A.[__]Z 32}{@/}{@set+Y A}{@echoj"\n"A,Y}
```

This is quite a messy mess...

But you can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/825bbd653f036fce8cc12f639c982ec5eed793ea
(Please don't use PHP 8.0.0)

Thanks [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush) for the idea that saved me 30 bytes.

---

**Ungolfed:**

This should be a lot easier to read.

```
{@set numbers as 0, 0, 0}

{@each argv.0 as letter key key}
    {@call ord into tmp letter}
    {@set% numbers.[key] tmp 32}
{@/}

{@set+ sum numbers}
{@echo separator "\n" numbers, sum}
```

---

**Explanation:**

I will explain how the golfed version works.

- `{@eachargv.0}` - loops through the first argument. `argv` is an array with all passed arguments.
  The ungolfed version defines variables for the key as value: `{@each argv.0 as letter key key}`.
  The default names are `_` for the value and `__` for the key.
- `{@callord intoZ _}` - calls the [function `ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) passing `_` as a value and storing into `Z`.
  `Z` is the same as `tmp` in the ungolfed version.
- `{@set%A.[__]Z 32}` - `set` is used to define a variable, and you can pass it a value.
  If you add a `%` before the variable, it calculates the remainder of the values (in this case, `Z` divided by 32).
  By magic, this handles letters A-Z and a-z, and maps them to A>1, B>2 ... Z>26.
  The result is stored into `A.[__]` (`numbers.[key]` in the ungolfed version).
- `{@/}` - closes the `@each` loop
- `{@set+Y A}` - `set` is used to define a variable, and you can pass it a value. If you add a `+` after, it indicates that it will receive the sum of all the passed values.
  In this case, it will sum all the numbers (`A`) and store into `Y`.
  The ungolfed version has `{@set+ sum numbers}`, which demonstrates a lot better the way it works.
- `{@echoj"\n"A,Y}` - Outputs `A` and `Y`, joined by `"\n"`.
  The ungolfed version has `{@echo separator "\n" numbers, sum}`.
  `@echoj` is just a shorthand for `@echo separator`.
  All values are separated by `"\n"`, regardless of their type.
  This doesn't output a newline at the end!

Comment: I don't know anything about this language but can you do `letter > ord > %32` (or `&31`) instead of `letter > upper > ord > -64` ? I guess it would save quite some bytes

Comment: @MarcMush I could try, yes, but the math is so incredibly rudimentar... To be honest, it was an afterthought. But luckly, I did implement the `%` operator, so, I will play around with it.

Comment: @MarcMush I've managed to use your idea, and saved 30 bytes. It looks even uglier, but works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, 55 bytes

```php
for(;$c=ord($argn[$i++])%32;$r+=$c)echo"$c
";echo"$r
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVkm3zi1I0VBKL0vOiVTK1tWM1VY2NrFWKtG1VkjVTkzPylVSSuZSsIawiIOv//6i80n/5BSWZ@XnF/3XdAA)

Quite straightforward solution..

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 35 bytes

```
j
:zhq
hx{y1py1pw*25xxY+zPY%*48py1p
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=j%0A%3Azhq%0Ahx%7By1py1pw*25xxY%2BzPY%25*48py1p&inputs=aBc)

Gets input, then starts moving left through the main program, which juggles the register, where the running sum is stored, and the stack, where the input and some calculations are stored. Once all letters are printed and added, execution moves up to the middle row, where the sum is printed and execution ends.

Comment: +1 for a cool language name

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 22 bytes

```
[explode[]%32]|.[],add
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z86taIgJz8lNTpW1dgotkYvOlYnMSXl/3@lRKdkJQA)

quite useful that `.[]` prints numbers with newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
echo,.(,+/)32|3 u:1!:1[3
```

Full program, -8 bytes thanks to [Conor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWO1KTM_J19DR0tPU1jY1qjBVKrQwVrQyjjSHSUFULFjuG-EOYAA)

```
echo,.(,+/)32|3 u:1!:1[3
                  1!:1[3  NB. read from stdin
              3 u:        NB. convert to char codes
           32|            NB. mod 32
      (,+/)               NB. monadic hook
        +/                NB. sum nums
       ,                  NB. append sum to nums
    ,.                    NB. make a column
echo                      NB. print
```

Comment: `tolower` isn't necessary here, since alphabetic ASCII characters are invariant under mod-32. e.g. `1 1 2 2-:3 u:'aAbB'`.

Comment: You can also get left-padding at the same bytecount with `echo"0` instead of `echo,.`

Comment: What a brainfart lol. I noticed the invariance and still applied `tolower`. Great catch. IG `echo"+` is also worth mentioning as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 53 <sup><s>60</s></sup> bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to @Julian*

> By encapsulating the first command in parenthesis, I was able to skip the second command which just printed $t and saved 1 byte. The other 6 bytes were from replacing ***$t='a','b','c'*** with ***$t=$args***.

```powershell
($t=$args|%{[byte][char]$_%32});($t|measure -sum).sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0OlxFYlsSi9uEa1OjqpsiQ1Njo5I7EoViVe1dioVtMaKF@Tm5pYXFqUqqBbXJqrqQck/v//r56orqCeBMTJ6gA)

**Explanation**

```powershell
($t=               # $t will be set to an array of ints returned
$args              # 'a','b','c' is passed through aka $args
|                  # pipes into the next command
%{                 # for loop
[byte][char]$_     # accepts char and returns int (ie. [byte][char]'a' returns 97)
%32                # x mod 32 returns position in alphabet 
})                 # completes for loop and encapsulation
;                  # divider between commands
($t                # passes the ints returned from the command above
|                  # pipe into next command
measure -sum       # measures the array and adds the sum property
).sum              # only returns the sum property
```

Comment: Hi James! Nice first answer! You can use the `$args` variable to pass arguments to your code block [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XEViWxKL24RrU6OqmyJDU2OjkjsShWJV7V2KjWWqXEWkOlpCY3NbG4tChVQbe4NFdTD0j8//9fPVFdQT0JiJPVAQ "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Also consider checking out some tips for golfing in powershell [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 60 bytes

```c
i,j;f(char*s){for(i=0;printf("%d\n",j=*s&31?:i),*s++;i+=j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSM5I7FIq1izOi2/SCPT1sC6oCgzryRNQ0k1JSZPSSfLVqtYzdjQ3ipTU0erWFvbOlPbNkvTuvZ/bmJmnoZmNRdQZbl/oZKmNVdBaUmxhhKIBRSL8isFsWr/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
j+=%R32CMQs
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B%3D%25R32CMQs&input=%22ZNu%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

-1 byte thanks to dingledooper!

```
func[a][s: 0 foreach c a[s: s + probe 1 * c % 32]print s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OjE2uthKwUAhLb8oNTE5QyFZIREkUKygrVBQlJ@UqmCooAUUVFUwNootKMrMK1Eojv2fpqBU7l@o9B8A)

Takes a 3-letter string as input. Iterates over the string, converts each character to an integer `(1 * c)` and maps it to `1-26` by `% 32`. Prints this at each step using `probe` (it returns a value) and updates the sum, which is printed at the end.

### Full program (works in Red console), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

-1 byte thanks to dingledooper!

```
s: 0 foreach c input[s: s + probe 1 * c % 32]print s
```

Comment: It appears that you can remove those parentheses to save a byte.

Comment: @dingledooper Thanks, indeed! The parentheses remained from an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
≔ＥＳ﹪℅ι³²θ⊞θΣθＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs5CoAwEAB7X2G5gdhoaSVWKYJC/MCioIGYO35/jTYDMzD7hXF3aIimlPRpQaIHYX3JKkdtT2C8le4oxsESD23RgK5p6FllYGOzlnRB4K0qNwT2hbplmDHl34k2sVD3mBc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ＥＳ﹪℅ι³²θ
```

Map the input string into ASCII ordinals and reduce modulo 32.

```
⊞θΣθ
```

Append the sum.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output everything in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 65 bytes

```
=LET(n,ROW(1:4),a,MOD(CODE(MID(A1&" ",n,1)),32),IF(n=4,SUM(a),a))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnF0ZoQH4IAt0Z75U?e=8VbbRN)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ëc %H
pUx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=y2MgJUgKcFV4&input=WyJaIiwiTiIsInUiXQ)

```
Ëc %H\npUx     :Implicit input of character array
Ë              :Map
 c             :  Charcode
   %H          :  Mod 32
     \n        :Assign to variable U
       p       :Push
        Ux     :  U reduced by addition
               :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç32%€=O?
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLuxkeqjpjW2/vb//yc7Vv3X1c3L181JrKoEAA) or [verify the entire alphabet at once](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X90X57t/8Ptxkaqj5rW2Prb//8PAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç         # Get the ASCII values of the characters in the (implicit) input-string
 32%      # Modulo each by 32
    €     # For-each over these integers:
     =    #  Print the integer with trailing newline (without popping)
      O   # Take the sum of the list
       ?  # And output it (without newline) as well
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
$♥%_Σ▐n
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/l0cylqvHnFj@aNiHv//9opWQlHSVHIK5SigUA)

**Explanation:**

```python
$        # Get the ordinal value of each character in the (implicit) input-list
 ♥%      # Modulo-32
   _     # Duplicate this list of integers
    Σ    # Sum the duplicated list
     ▐   # Append it to the original list
      n  # Join this list by newlines
         # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 3 inividual chars as input: (Not sure if allowed)

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 73 bytes

```java
(a,b,c)->System.out.print(a%32+"\n"+b%32+"\n"+c%32+"\n"+(a%32+b%32+c%32))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LCoMwEDzrVyxC0eDj0B6lhR499OStj8MmpjbWFyZKS/HbbUxFOrA7y75mChwwLLLn1Pa0FAxYiVLCCUUNHxs0RK14d0fGIVk6M4ZGZMBfnHnsgR1gAIbpwozEZnU02aTlv1SoNJn7Sqt4qepEnV9ugF0uyZ9EAhz2MHkY0ICR8JC@peJV1PQqavWJ8nCz2/rOtXZ8ulZsrX5jM5mbhEyxbVk8Mqbdoxu4VMfZ1U6t0R6nLw)

Using a string as input:

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 110 bytes

```java
s->{byte[]a=s.getBytes();System.out.print(a[0]%32+"\n"+a[1]%32+"\n"+a[2]%32+"\n"+(a[0]%32+a[1]%32+a[2]%32));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9NC4JQEDzXr1iEwIcofRzFoI5Cp26Zh9Vej2d@4a5RhL/dXmLWXGZnZxiYDO/oZpdbX7dJrlNIcySCA@oSXnMw0CXL5oqphHD8fHCv9AXkQ6b2kRtdKiDhD2Y3H2hsI0Y2NKQL0zmmoxiwUST@CqcjBAUB9ORuX8mTZRRjQJ6SvDeCbOEfn8Sy8KqWvdp0sY3RMl5s1o51Li0Ho9W/WP/ElPtGRlcIv/N7gJnyhj3WLjlZ05iufwM)

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 122 bytes

```python
Count i while i-4 {
(_/80+_%80)*80+N%32
_/80^(i/3)
Count t while _%80/10*0^t {
Write _%80/10+48
}
Write _%10+48
Write 10
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPXRKGaSyNe38JAO17VwkBTC8jwUzU24gIJxWlk6htrckG0lEC1gJTpGxpoGcSVALWGF2WWwMW0TSy4auFCED6EZ2jAVfv/v6NfFQA)

#### Explanation

We conceptually partition the accumulator into two sections, `_/80` and `_%80`. The latter holds each letter's index; the former holds the running sum of letter indices. (The number 80 is chosen because it's both divisible by 10 and larger than any number we'll have to handle.) We loop four times: each time, we read a new character into `_%80` and add the previous character's index to `_/80`, but on the fourth iteration we then divide the accumulator by 80, effectively moving the sum into the `_%80` slot. We then output the one-or-two-digit number in `_%80`, followed by a newline.

```python
# Loop four times
Count i while i - 4 {
    # Set _ to: sum of _/80 and _%80, times 80, plus character code from stdin mod 32
    (_ / 80 + _ % 80) * 80 + (N % 32)
    # If i = 3, divide _ by 80; if i < 3, no-op
    _ / 80 ^ (i / 3)
    # Loop once if _%80 >= 10
    Count t while (_ % 80) / 10 * (1 - t) {
        # Print the tens digit of _%80
        Write (_ % 80) / 10 + 48
    }
    # Print the ones digit of _%80
    Write (_ % 80) % 10 + 48
    # Print a newline
    Write 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 38 bytes

```js
for i;echo $[j=##$i:u-64,k+=j,j]
<<<$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCHTOjU5I19BJTrLVllZJdOqVNfMRCdb2zZLJyuWy8bGRiX7fy1XmkKVQpBC4n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
O32%DST
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6Fsv9jY1UXYJDIDyo4ILFUX6lECYA)

##### Explanation

```python
O32%DST  # Implicit input
O        # Ordinals
 32%     # Mod 32
    D    # Duplicate
     ST  # Append sum
         # N flag joins by newlines
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$8\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 6.585 bytes

```
SM',%32C
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTTScsJTMyQyIsIltaLE4sdV0iXQ==)

Sorta-port of 05AB1E.

```
SM',%32C # Takes input as a list of chars
 M'      # Map each char
       C # Get the charcode
    %32  # Modulo 32
   ,     # And print (returning the thing printed)
S        # Sum the resulting list
         # Which gets implicitly printed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 75 <sup><s>107</s></sup> bytes

> *-32 bytes.
>
> I don't know why i didn't think sooner of using `peek` even though it has been invented specifically for this kind of case!*

Using only a single inline Java Stream, takes String as parameter.

```java
s->System.out.print(s.chars().map(e->e%32).peek(System.out::println).sum())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRaoMwFEDf@xUXZZA8mKKdHSjtF3TbQ9@27CHVa2cbr6mJ3cbot7vUCoOxQB5yOZyc5KDOKmoN0qE8Dqbf6bqAQitr4VHVBN@zGUBNDrtKFQgbPwC/zm1dQsW2rqtpD5bnfnq5otYp5w0b0LAabLTeflmHjWh7J4xnHbOieFedZVw0yjCM1ni3SLgwiEf2C2fZSGviwvYN43zIr/apb7pkjGh85dTx@gaq21t@iwbQomLBx/Mp4Lk/zeeAnwYLhyVkkCwkxanfD5LSdMT/pmpigaQwDIPxeZPv5an/17f0rntJSSxpGd9@4zL8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 <sup><s>55</s></sup> bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @xigoi !*

For the first time, i got the shortest JS answer!

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(e=>(a+=e%=32,e),a=0).join`
`+`
`+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxDoIwFEDRna9oSkzagCAgmJiUwQ/Q3XSggVcCwVekoP59xc0Yhzve06uHsvXUjfMWTQNOC2dFeVq0holZHt3UyECUTAUCNiJLQ@ChEjse9abDyquCT8rVBq0ZIBpMyzSjz8udck4IiWMCrxHqGRpyJGkmMcnXDhLz3PueqO/7lHs/zvW8/HWK1dhLTBOJReLe)

---

Alternative solution using an accumulator for the resulting string to try to get rid of the join and the double newline (**56 bytes**, improved with @xigoi's tip too) :

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(e=>(a+=(e%=32)+`
`,b+=e),a="",b=0)&&a+b
```

---

Alternative way to calculate the sum and regroup before joining (**56 bytes**. I wonder if the 2 join could be declared only once and called 2 times with different parameters) :

```javascript
s=>[...r=Buffer(s).map(e=>e%32),eval(r.join`+`)].join`
`
```

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcyxDoIwFEDRna9oSkzagCAgmJiUwQ/Q3XSggVcCwVekoP59xc0Yhzve06uHsvXUjfMWTQNOC2dFeVq0holZHt3UyECUDDYiS0MVCAiBh0rseNSbDiuvCj4pVxu0ZoBoMC3TjD4vd8o5ISSOCbxGqGdoyJGkmcQkXztIzHPve6K@71Pu/TjX8/LXKVZjLzFNJBaJewM)

Comment: Actually, [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcyxDoIwFEDRna9oSkzagCAgmJiUwQ/Q3XSggVcCwVekoP59xc0Yhzve06uHsvXUjfMWTQNOC2dFeVq0holZHt3UyECUTAUCNiJLQ@ChEjse9abDyquCT8rVBq0ZIBpMyzSjz8udck4IiWMCrxHqGRpyJGkmMcnXDhLz3PueqO/7lHs/zvW8/HWK1dhLTBOJReLe)

Comment: @xigoi Thank you for your tip! I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.5.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.5.1), 155 bytes

```
func main:
in ""
conv ~arr:char
dup
dup
lda 0
sta $1
.lbl a
ldelem $1
conv i32
push 31
and
dup
print.n
push $a
add
pop $a
inc $1
push $1
push 3
sub
brtrue a
push $a
print.n
ret
end
```

A simple loop which goes over each character.

**Explanation:**

```
func main:
    ; Get the input as a string, then convert it to an array of characters
    in ""
    conv ~arr:char

    ; Duplicate the array twice
    dup
    dup

    ; Initialize $a and $1 to 0
    lda 0
    sta $1
    
.lbl a
    ; Load the character at index $1, convert it to an integer, bitwise-AND it with 31, duplicate it, then print it
    ldelem $1
    conv i32
    push 31
    and
    dup
    print.n

    ; Add the duplicated value to $a
    push $a
    add
    pop $a

    ; Increment $1 and break from the loop when $1 == 3
    inc $1
    push $1
    push 3
    sub
    brtrue a

    ; Print $a, which now contains the sum of the characters
    push $a
    print.n

    ret
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 28 bytes

```
!3wi' %.?+!/ O \t.$K?/ O \@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/RuDxTXUFVz15bUV/BXyGmRE/F2x7McuD6/z/RKRkA)

The trailing new line is required for the ordinal mode to work.

```
!          Initialises the sum to 0
3w         Main loop with 3 iterations
i' %       Reads one character from the input as its ascii code, modulus 32 (32 is the ascii code of <space>)
.?+!       Adds the index of the character to the sum
/ O \      Prints the current character index
t.$K       End of the loop
?/ O \@    Prints the sum and exits
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ÄDSa
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyU4NERTYSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PVpOdSZmbGFncz1OZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
ÄDSa  # Implicit input
Ä     # Num to alphabet
 DS   # Sum without popping
   a  # Append the sum
      # Join on newlines
      # Implicit output
```