# Output a random unary string

Tags: code-golf, random, open-ended-function

Your task is simple: output the letter `x` a random number of times. Every possible length of `x`s must have a non-zero probability of being output.

Of course, there must be some lengths whose probabilities tend to \$ 0 \$, in order for the total probabilities to sum to \$ 1 \$, but all must still be theoretically possible.

- You may choose whether to include the empty string as a possible output
- You may have any consistent separator between the `x`s, and you may output the separator more than once. The separator may not contain the unary character
- You may use any other consistent single character instead of `x`
- Per standard rules, [your program must always halt](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785) in finite time. (Terminating "with probability 1" [is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17122), though)
- You can assume your language's random number generator is perfectly random. If it is supposedly continuous, you may assume it has infinite precision.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24520)

Comment: I'd like to  emphasize how well specified this challenge is. This is not common for challenges involving randomness

Comment: Does 'every possible length of Xs' include zero Xs?  Currently different answers seem to make different assumptions for this...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen "You may choose whether to include the empty string as a possible output"

Comment: @LuisMendo A sandbox success story! It went through several revisions there.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a *full program*?

Comment: "Of course, there must be some lengths whose probabilities tend to 0"  This is a bit of an odd phrase.  The probability of a single event can't really tend towards anything.  But if we are talking about sequences, for every sequence of lengths whose probabilities don't tend towards zero that sequence must repeat some length an infinite number of times. :)

Comment: @Seggan [Default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) apply. You can submit a full program, or a function which takes no input and returns a string

Comment: If my language does not support strings, can I output a unary number instead? Like, if I were to output `111...` as a number instead of a string, is that ok?

Comment: @AidenChow Yes that's fine, as long as your language's number type can hold arbitrarily large values

Comment: @pxeger uhhh, so the language I'm using is Desmos, and there is a maximum value for Desmos, which is around \$1.79769\cdot10^{308}\$, that is based on Javascript's [MAX_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE). So does that make my submission invalid?

Comment: For now, I'm going to assume my answer is invalid and delete my answer.

Comment: Is it permissible for the separator mentioned in the rules to consist of a finite repetition of the same character `x` in question?

Comment: @archaephyrryx No, I can't allow that. (I'll clarify so that the separator cannot contain `x`)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I don't have much time to work on ATO lately but IIRC Nibbles was one of the languages that unexplainably doesn't work (and I've been unable to fix it). FYI the best way to contact me is via the [ATO chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122645/attempt-this-online)

Answer (score 14):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
x7n
```

Terminates on an error once x sends the IP left.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8I87/9/AA)

4 bytes:

```
x7
n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8KcK@//fwA)

This will terminate with an error when `n` has been executed more times than `7`, which has probability 1 of eventually occurring, thought there is no upper limit on how many times `7` will be executed first.

Answer (score 9):

## MATLAB, <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```MATLAB
while rand<.5 disp(1),end
```

Outputs "1" a random number of times, with newline in between. Each length l of has half the probability of length l-1.

Thanks @Luis Mendo for the 3 bytes!

Comment: Nice first answer! Thanks for fixing it :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 43 bytes

```
setrand(getwalltime)
while(random,print(1))
```

(Don't) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/vzi1pCgxL0UjPbWkPDEnpyQzN1WTqzwjMydVAySen6tTUJSZV6JhqKn5/z8A) This version is very likely to time out on TIO; here's a slightly longer version that produces nicer results: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/vzi1pCgxL0UjPbWkPDEnpyQzN1WTqzwjMydVAySen6tqqVNQlJlXomGoqfn/PwA)

#### Explanation

```
setrand(getwalltime)
```

Seed the random number generator with `getwalltime`, which is "time in ms since UNIX Epoch."

```
while(random,print(1))
```

While a random integer in the range \$[0,2^{31})\$ is not equal to zero, print `1` with a trailing newline.

Comment: I suppose the first line is because there's a default fixed random number seed,  meaning the number of 1's would actually not be random?

Comment: I *think* you don't need the `%9`.

Comment: Yeah, it gave the same result every time when I didn't seed the generator. I agree that the `%9` is theoretically not necessary, but since the odds of getting exactly a zero are so astronomically small (1 in 2^31, apparently), it simply timed out on TIO. I guess I can change the code, add an explanation, and give the longer-but-more-usable version in the TIO link.

Comment: i was 2 days too late to post a PARI/GP post :( took me 2 days to find out how to actually use this lang specifically for this qns

Answer (score 9):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
{×₴₀℅|
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%C3%97%E2%82%B4%E2%82%80%E2%84%85%7C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

We use v2.4.1 because it seems in 2.6 and later there's no way to get a random bit in two bytes.

```
{      # Forever...
 ×₴    # Print an asterisk
     | # While...
   ₀℅  # A random bit is nonzero
```

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
while(rexp(1))cat(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVoyi1okDDUFMzObEESP3/DwA)

3 bytes longer than [Giuseppe's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243531/95126), but can output unary values greater than 2147483647.

In fact, it will nearly *always* output unary values that are significantly greater than 2147483647, since the chance of stopping after any outputted `1` character is about `1e-324` (the lower limit of [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s double-precision numeric type, below which values are truncated to zero).
This will also nearly always exceed the output limit on TIO, so [here](https://tio.run/##ZY/BTsQwDETv/YqR9rCNVCoCnCr1W1BIXGopJFXibhd@viSrpRJwsuOM53nSfoKjiQPBxw1LIsuZY8CF0q3GCedE1@WMaQ1Wyqg5oWVHQdgaD4nIYoIzyf0VdnhbBRvLjBj8J3QhWf4oS4s3lqr1weuKa464GL9ShqecIbMJeOw1TCKkuAZHruK@KMUOHLKQcdXk35Kmh@enFzU0Tcn0ejDGn8Pa0nSO31nyqNUxvXZ936sbqSru77tQNTXc@MuwLcklD0P9Ufs2s6e29q1WyhopZd@/AQ) is a link using a modified version of the `rexp` function with only 1 decimal place of precision.

Answer (score 8):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
⌂v▲
```

Pushes `*` with a probability of \$\frac{4\text{,}294\text{,}967\text{,}294}{4\text{,}294\text{,}967\text{,}295}\$ (99.999999999767%) each iteration, and won't include the empty output (so will always output at least one `*`).

*Don't try it online.*

**Previous 4 [byter](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py):**

```
⌂v¶▼
```

Pushes `*` with a probability of \$\frac{837\text{,}973\text{,}946}{858\text{,}993\text{,}459}\$ (~97.55%) each iteration, and won't include the empty output (so will always output at least one `*`).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9RT1PZoW2Ppu35/x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
  ▲   # Do while falsey with pop:
⌂     #  Push character '*'
 v    #  Push a random integer in the range [-2³¹, 2³¹)
      #  (only 0 is a falsey integer in MathGolf)
      # (after which the entire joined stack is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
   ▼  # Do while truthy with pop:
⌂     #  Push character '*'
 v    #  Push a random integer in the range [-2³¹, 2³¹)
  ¶   #  Pop and check if this integer is a (positive) prime number
      # (after which the entire joined stack is output implicitly as result)
```

The mentioned probability is basically the amount of non-prime numbers within the range \$[-2^{31},2^{31})\$ (which is \$4\text{,}189\text{,}869\text{,}730\$ [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%5E31+%2B+2%5E31-1+-+%28count+primes+less+than+2%5E31%29)) as numerator and total amount of integers within the range \$[-2^{31},2^{31})\$ (basically \$2^{32}-1=4\text{,}294\text{,}967\text{,}295\$) as denominator (and then simplified by dividing both by their greatest common divisor \$5\$).

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes by noodle man

```javascript
_=>''.padEnd(1/Math.random())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADA3Y/Yxog4I26OvsE0AorB1iDx@3h30UfvnuNTehbna7B1s3Pbqofcwg7GYaVyqkzs5AbEapogGaLVJk6j1qbrIu7CrySvkhwQAFXyfJQT6w8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
f=_=>Math.random()>.5?'':1+f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbe1s43sSRDrygxLyU/V0PTTs/UXl3dylA7TUPzvzVXWn6RRqatgXWmjaGBgbW2dqZmcn5ecX5Oql5OfroGUI3mfwA)

Simple

Comment: AH! Beat me to it, was thinking of this ever since I first saw it in the sandbox

Comment: `Math.random()` may output 0. So you may omit the `>.5` in first program.

Comment: you can also omit the `f=` on the first one

Comment: @CreaZyp154 It's required for recursion

Comment: @EnderShadow8 ah yes, didn't see

Comment: I would have used `<.5` as that would have given an exact 50% probability of recursion.

Comment: Would the first one be invalid due to max recursion depth? Or is it fine because it's implementation specific, not in the JS standard?

Comment: @MatthewJensen [We generally don't care about practical issues like recursion limits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2289/46076)

Comment: [29 bytes using `''.padEnd(n)` instead of `'x'.repeat(n)`](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADA3Y/Yxog4I26OvsE0AorB1iDx@3h30UfvnuNTehbna7B1s3Pbqofcwg7GYaVyqkzs5AbEapogGaLVJk6j1qbrIu7CrySvkhwQAFXyfJQT6w8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
1X/r
```

Outputs one or more `1`s (usually not very many of them). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZLDCP0iyBMqAhMBgA)

#### Explanation

```
   r  Random number in [0, 1)
  /   Invert
1X    Repeat 1 that many times
```

Theoretically, I think it's possible for this to output nothing if `r` returns exactly `0`, but that's within the rules anyway.

Comment: (Repeating from elsewhere) Because r has finite precision technically it cannot output every number. In theory some kind of lazy evaluator with arbitrary precision could do it.

Comment: Curiosity: if we chose a certain function instead of 1/r, the program could halt with probability 1 and still have average runtime infinity.

Comment: Correct; however, for this particular challenge, "You can assume your language's random number generator is perfectly random. If it is supposedly continuous, **you may assume it has infinite precision**."

Answer (score 6):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [je je](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103412/je-je)'s observation that Null bytes are accebtale as output.*

```
+[>.?]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMS8nP1U0qSszMSytNzv7/XzvaTs8@9v9/AA)

Outputs at least 1 `0x01` character, and terminates each iteration with a 1/256 chance. `?` sets the current cell to a random byte, and this will only terminate when that byte is 0.

### Detailed Explanation

```
+       set first cell to 1
[       while the current cell is non-zero:
  >         move right one cell
  .         output it (0x00)
  ?         set current cell to a random byte from 0 to 255
]       end while
```

Comment: Is the second plus necessary? I'm not aware of a specification that would prevent the null byte being a valid output character.

Comment: @jeje True! Great observation.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
main=print 1>>randomIO>>=([main]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XKzcxM8@2oCgzr0TB0M6uCCzo6W9nZ6sRDZKKVVTU/P8fAA)

Random improvements applied to [AZTECCO's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243550/78410). Halts by non-recoverable error, so it needs to be a full program. Prints at least once, but has \$\frac{1}{2^{64}}\$ chance of continuing to print. (The return type of `randomIO` is inferred to be `Int`, which is a signed 64-bit integer in TIO's environment.)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
f=do print 1;n<-randomIO;mapM_ id[f|n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK802JV@hoCgzr0TB0DrPRrcILOzpb52bWOAbr5CZEp1Wkxf7PzcxM8827T8A)

A function that terminates gracefully and has 1/2 chance of continuing. `[f|n]` becomes `[f]` or `[]` with 1/2 chance each, and `mapM_ id` (one byte shorter than `sequence_`) runs all monads in the list sequentially. Deleting `_` results in a type inference error.

Answer (score 6):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 20 bytes

```
x::=xx
x::=~x
::=
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/v8LKyraiggtE1VVwAUmuCq7//wE) (I'm not sure why the final blank line is necessary, but the program doesn't output anything if I delete it.)

#### Explanation

Thue starts with an initial string and executes rewriting rules nondeterministically until it cannot execute any more, at which point it halts. This program consists of two rules:

```
x::=xx
```

Replace an `x` in the string with `xx`.

```
x::=~x
```

Delete an `x` from the string and output `x`.

The program's starting string is:

```
x
```

Thus, at each stage of execution, the string consists of one or more `x`s; it can either get longer by one `x`, or get shorter by one `x` and output an `x`. Once all the `x`s have been output, the program halts. This occurs with probability 1, although in practice sometimes the interpreter segfaults.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```r
strrep(1,rexp(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikqCi1QMNQpyi1Akhpav7/DwA)

Samples from an \$Exp(1)\$ distribution to determine the length. This allows any positive real number to be generated, which `strrep` truncates, though most of them will be rather small.

Comment: Nice.  Or [+5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVoyi1okDDUNPGUjM5sQTI@P8fAA) to get a non-zero probability of outputting unary values greater than 2147483648...

Comment: I was more worried about the result of ```strrep(1,x)``` when ```x``` is greater than ```2^32```...  although obviously this will be rather a rare event...

Comment: oh, true. well, I take it back, you can post your 22 byter if you'd like.

Comment: I realised that I could shave-off 2 more bytes (I think...), so I've [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243569/95126) it as a 'very large output' version...

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda:'x'*int(1/(1-random()))
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3jXISc5NSEq3UK9S1MvNKNAz1NQx1ixLzUvJzNTQ1NbnSivJzFSB8hczcgvyiEi2oToW0_CKFTIXMPJB0eqqGoammFZeCQkERyJg0oGaIugULIDQA)

*Thanks to users `pxeger` and `DominicVanEssen` for their clarifications.*

Outputs the character `x` a random number of times. Random sequences of `x`s are separated by the newline character.

Comment: Not valid because random() has finite precision, hence not all numbers could be generated, unfortunately.

Comment: @Real OP explicitly states infinite precision may be assumed.

Comment: I believe you can use `random()` instead of `(1-random())`

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev `random()` can generate `0.0`, which would cause a division by zero, in this code.

Comment: @solid.py Can’t it also generate `1.0`?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev No, it actually cannot. For more info see the documentation at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `random.c`, <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 21 bytes

```
[ 1 . rand 9 > ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JQlJiXkp@rl6yQm1iSoZCdWpSXmqNg/T9awVBBDyypYKlgpxCrkJOfX/D/PwA)

This uses similar logic as flipping a coin until it lands on tails. Only you're using a severely weighted coin, so you usually get heads, leading to fairly long runs. `rand` is C's `rand()` function, returning an integer between 0 and 2147483647 (probably, though it doesn't matter). Each iteration of the loop, print `1` followed by a newline. If the output of `rand` is greater than 9, perform another iteration; otherwise, end the program.

Answer (score 5):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), <strike>30</strike> 26

```bash
for((;RANDOM;));{ echo x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhf/T8tv0hDwzrI0c/F39daU9O6WiE1OSNfocK69n9tTXnyfwA)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>62</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```python
import os
while os.urandom(1)[0]:print(1)
```

[Try online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3NTNzC_KLShTyi7nKMzJzUoEMvdKixLyU_FwNQ81og1irgqLMvBIgG6IBqg-mHwA)

Thanks to @pxeger, @mvirts, @MarcMush and @loopywalt.

Comment: Using a `*` import is 1 byte shorter: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3bdOK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFlexrXqFOld5RmZOKlgqM69EQ9dQx1DTqlgbLFVQBBIq1oQYAjULZiYA. You can also initialise `s` to an empty string, since you're allowed to choose whether or not to include the empty string as an output. It will also be shorter to use a random integer in the range 0 to 2 instead, because there's no negative sign (but still with the same random effect): https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rdOK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFlexrbo6V3lGZk4qWCYzr0TDQMdI06pY21a9Qp2roAgkUqwJMQJqEsxEAA

Comment: Also FYI, you can generate a template for your answer on ATO, including the language header and try-it-online link, by clicking the blue clipboard button in the top right corner and choosing "CGCC post"

Comment: @pxeger Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: The wildcard import is the same length as it is, but you can remove the space before the `*` to get the improvement.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by initializing s to `"x"` and adding it to itself. (i.e. `s+=s`)

Comment: @GingerIndustries That wouldn't have any chance of outputting strings with lengths other than powers of 2. [Should be able to cut `s` out entirely though.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3TdOK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFld5RmZOKlgwM69Ew0DHUNOqoAjETM1LsVWvUNeEaIaaATMLAA)

Comment: Agreed, cut out s and use random with no args?
[45 bytes?](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ddOK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFld5RmZOKlRQQ9OqoCgzr0RDvUJdE6IJqhdmBgA)

Comment: @MVirts Thanks I edited.

Comment: -2 bytes: `print(1)` instead of `print('x')`

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks, I changed the answer!

Comment: [-2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3NTNzC_KLShTyi7nKMzJzUoEMvdKixLyU_FwNQ81og1irgqLMvBIgG6IBqg-mHwA) use `os.urandom`.

Comment: @loopywalt does it return an empty string of bytes for termination of the program?

Comment: Nope, indexing a byte string returns an int in Python 3. The program terminates when this int is 0.

Comment: @loopywalt Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2ȮX$’¿
```

A niladic Link that prints `2`s as a side-effect (it also yields `1`). Only prints strictly positive numbers (as allowed in the specification).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/oxLoIlUcNMw/t/39oUdr//wA)** (The footer suppresses the printing of `1` that a full program would otherwise do implicitly.)
Or [see forty at once](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//MsiuWCTigJnCv//CouG4nzHhuYQp//80MA) (plus a single trailing newline).

#### How?

```
2ȮX$Ḋ¿ - Link: no arguments
2      - two - let's call this V
     ¿ - while...
    ’  - ...condition: decrement V (V=2 -> 1 (truthy); V=1 -> 0 (falsey))
   $   - ...do: last two links as a monad - f(V):
 Ȯ     -   print V, yield V
  X    -   random integer in [1,V] -> next V = 1 or 2 (probability = 0.5)
```

---

Previous @ 7 bytes:

```
2XȮß$Ị¡
```

A niladic Link that prints `1`s as a side-effect (it also yields `2`). This one includes the empty output (i.e. zero).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//MljIrsOfJOG7isKh/8KiZv//) (The footer suppresses the printing of `2` that a full program would otherwise do implicitly.)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
`1rEk
```

Outputs `1` separated by newlines `n` times, where `n` is a (shifted) geometric random variable with parameter `1/2`. This means `n` is `1,2,3...` with probability `1/2`,`1/4`, `1/8` ... The program halts with probability `1`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8GwyDX7/38A)

```
`     % Do...while
  1   %   Push 1
  r   %   Push uniform random number in the interval (0,1)
  E   %   Multiply by 2
  k   %   Round down. This gives 0 or 1 with probability 1/2
      % End (implicit). The top of the stack is used as loop condition
      % If 1 a new iteration is executed, otherwise the loop is exited
      % Display stack (implicit)
```

Comment: I believe `\`1rYo` also works (I like it because it says "Yo" at the end).

Comment: @SundarR Good point! Yes, that also works

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[?₄Ω#
```

Outputs `0`s with a probability of \$\frac{3}{4}\$ each time. Could be a probability of \$\frac{2}{3}\$ or \$\frac{1}{2}\$ for the same byte-count by replacing the `₄` with `т` or `T` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2v5RU8u5lcr//wMA)

**Explanation:**

```python
[      # Loop indefinitely:
 ?     #  Print an empty string without newline in the first iteration,
       #  or the 0 that was previously on the stack in other iterations
  ₄    #  Push 1000 (or 100 for `т` or 10 for `T`)
   Ω   #  Pop and push a random digit from this integer
    #  #  If it's 1: stop the infinite loop
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 6 bytes

```
$/
.x/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X0WfS69C//9/AA)

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 6 bytes

```
\$
.|x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P0aFS6@m4v9/AA)

*Likely* optimal, considering one row has to have width at least 3 for `$` to produce distinct random outcomes.

Both programs consist of two random branches from `$`, one of which returns the codepoint of `x`, and the other of which prints (the character value of) and returns the return value of (a fresh evaluation of) the `$`.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic (TI-84), <sup><s>11</s></sup> 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
Repeat checkTmr(startTmr
Disp 1
End
```

the program can only end when the check `checkTmr(startTmr` happens between two seconds (`checkTmr(startTmr) = 1` instead of `0`). This way, any number of ones is possible (the shortest I got was 3 ones, the longest printed during approx 10 seconds)

`Repeat` always executes the loop the first time, so the empty string is not included (`repeat until` or `do while not`)

For calculators without time (TI-83), replace `checkTmr(startTmr` with `rand>.9`  but it's not true randomness (same output on each reset of the calculator)

Comment: `You can assume your language's random number generator is perfectly random. If it is supposedly continuous, you may assume it has infinite precision.` The 10 byte solution using rand is perfectly acceptable per the rules of the challenge

Comment: the problem with `rand` in TI-Basic is that the same numbers will happen when the calculator is reset, [which is the default](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52967/98541). I can't find a meta answer about it though, so maybe it can be discussed

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
Ｗ‽φx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUEjKDEvJT9Xw9DAwEBTUyGgKDOvREOpQknT@v///7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Prints an average of 999 `x`s. (Other average counts from `1` to `9` are also possible by substituting an appropriate character for `φ`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>10</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
1#~>.@%?0
```

-1 byte by using Reflex `~` instead of Bond `&1`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZXr7PQcVO0N/mtycaUmZ@QrpP0HAA)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't understand anything. I used the old fashioned approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 29 bytes

```c
f(){putchar(63)&rand()&&f();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxDoQgEER7vmJjQXZjTIgmNtz9iQ1B0S1Eg1x14dtxKefNm/HD7n2tAel//7I/XMJ5Ip1cXJG0Fm5L5ZjhdBxBLPW0DjDzuaEhsipcCbAp/DWWP6Oxfc8iQhsrkNsHuyV2Eooq9QU)

Comment: `putchar(1)` or `puts("?")` or even `puts("")` would be shorter, and technically abiding by the requirements

Comment: @Conor O'Brien I haven't seen the separator specs, so f(){rand(puts("1"))&&f();} should be ok, there's near 0% of possibilities of having a short output but it may be fine

Answer (score 3):

## [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), <s>58</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
String f(){return.5<Math.random()?"":1+f();}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kK7EsccHN2ILSpJzMZIXknMTiYgXfxMy8aqhIcUliCZAqy89MUcgFimsElxRl5qVHxyZqVnMFVxaXpObq5ZeW6BUARUty8jTSNDQ1rWu5UHQvLS1J07W4qQPRqgBUUl2UWlJalKdnauObWJKhV5SYl5Kfq6Fpr6RkZagNlLeuhehZCKUXLIDQAA)

-1 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Same strategy as the [NodeJS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243526/107299) answer. Previous answer did not fit challenge spec, this version turned out to be shorter as well.

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `return Math.random()>.5` to `return.5<Math.random()`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
Dot@@Table[x,1/Random[]]
```

Thanks to att for –4!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X6RgZfvfJb/EwSEkMSknNbpCx1A/KDEvJT83OjYWKBEdUJSZVxJdFKujYGgQ@x8A)

Comment: 25 bytes if a list output is allowed: `x~Table~Floor[1/Random[]]`

Comment: Yes I had that one too but decided against it because of the curly braces.

Comment: @GregMartin Even better, `Floor` isn't needed in `Table`, so we can have `Sequence` output in 24 bytes with `##&@@Table[x,1/Random[]]`

Comment: @att this generates `Sequence[x, x, x, x]` which I find even less appealing than `Table[x,1/Random[]]` (19 bytes).

Comment: I'd argue to the contrary that `Sequence` is the most natural head (besides `String`) for such an output, as it fills in arguments when under any head. If you don't like it `Dot` is the same length as `##&`.

Comment: Alright, with `Dot` I'm fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 19 bytes

```
grep -oam1 x /*/ur*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhab04tSCxR08xNzDRUqFPS19EuLtCAyUAUwhQA)

Explanation:

- `/*/ur*`: glob for `/dev/urandom`, an infinite stream of random bytes
- `grep x`: search for the letter `x`
- `-o`: print only the letter `x`s
- `-a`: force output even though `/dev/urandom` is a binary file
- `-m1`: quit after the first matching line

---

## Pure Zsh, 20 bytes

```
for ((;RANDOM;))<<<x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZb0vKLFDQ0rIMc_Vz8fa01NW1sbCogUlAVMJUA)

Loop breaks with probability \$ \frac 1 {32768} \$ for each iteration.

Explanation:

- `for ((;RANDOM;))`: loop while `$RANDOM` (which is a random integer in the range \$ [0, 32768) \$, is nonzero
- `<<<x`: print `x`

Here's a version for 2 bytes more with a probability of  \$ \frac 1 2 \$, and is much more easy to demonstrate:

```
for ((;RANDOM%2;))<<<x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhbb0vKLFDQ0rIMc_Vz8fVWNrDU1bWxsKiCSUDUwtQA)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 28 bytes

```
@if %random% gtr 9 echo x&%0
```

Outputs an average of about 3276 `x`s, assuming `CMD.EXE` doesn't stack overflow first.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
9w9ṙ9|↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/37Lc8uHOmZY1j9o2/P//HwA)

#### Explanation

```
9w         Write 9
  9ṙ       Pick a random integer in 0..9
    9      If it is 9, terminate
     |↰    Else, recurse
```

Comment: Should be able to drop the `|` for failure-terminated recursion, unfortunately sacrificing longer strings being reasonably likely (doesn't seem likely there's a way to boost the chance of success over [1/2](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KJnOKIpyjihrDigoHiiKjhurjhuoniiqUp/zF3P@G5mT/ihrD///8))

Answer (score 3):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 14 bytes

```
_->Out__+_
_->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XtfOv7QkPl47ngvI/P8fAA)

Breaks the loop with probability \$\frac12\$ at each iteration.

#### Explanation

The program starts with a single `_` atom.  Since both instructions consume only a `_` atom, they are both satisfied and one is chosen randomly.  The first outputs the number of `_` atoms remaining (0) and produces another `_` atom to continue the loop.  The second just consumes the atom, ending the loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
!_=.1<rand()&&!show(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHeVs/QpigxL0VDU01NsTgjv1zDUPN/Wn6RQqZCZp6CoZWhgQGXYl5@SUZmXjpXQVFmXklOnoYmV2peyn8A)

Comment: This seems similar to the javascript solution, but I'm not quite sure how it works

Answer (score 3):

## [C++](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), <del>112</del> 86 bytes

-26 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-stringhttps://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){srand(time(0));for(int i=0;i<rand()%100;i++){std::cout<<1;}}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##HcpNCoAgEEDhfacIIlAi0K1ad5HRYiB/sGkVnt2k5eN7kPN6ArQ2YYTrcd5guql4G/YhWIyMv3ex0THC4JngXB@pMIw04iY0mt/4LEWPZekzOaUgPWSM1LW29gE)

Comment: Shorter without the `#define` and typedef (and you can even remove the return type of `main` for a warning).

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##HchLCoAgEADQfacIInCIQLcq3UVGi4H8oOMqOrtBb/mwlP1CHGOhhHf3wVJuXIOLx0SJZzLRURLwnLmKVl3ygikGIQEMbZv9B1YlpYHGXmvMna1V5h3jAw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## x86 32-bit machine code (Linux), 22 bytes

```
00000000: 31db f7e3 4243 6a31 89e1 0404 cd80 580f  1...BCj1......X.
00000010: c7f0 a801 75ea                           ....u.
```

Asssembly:

```asm
section .text
	global main
main:
	;call write(fd=ebx, *buf=ecx, count=edx)
	xor ebx, ebx	;ebx=0
	mul ebx		;eax=edx=0
	inc edx		;edx=1
	inc ebx		;ebx=1
	push 0x31	;push '1'
	mov ecx, esp 	;ecx=ptr to '1'
	add al, 4	;eax=4
	int 0x80	;syscall to print '1'
	pop eax		;fix stack

	;get rand & loop
	rdrand eax	;eax=rand()
	test al, 1	;eax%2==0?
	jnz main 	;if so, jmp to main
```

There is a 50% probability for each character printed for another one to print.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJBbtswEDyLrxgYqJMalmLLORSxlQJFW7SHIkDPvVAUJdOVSFWkGjro350lVSARkAuxO5yd2V2y5PZ4EdzhcPjy8BX3uHFdf8MzbruLlcIpo5E56R1LmtaUvEXHlWbhuGPJXvC2xeOgnLyuq0KWfo1VOdaFFBQJM2pXyMq/Z4k3A@I1HcmejmLDkm5sY04A94EYQKUFKAwgAdv/wMQqI9CP9oiN322TfQyvtlekZf4iukrbg6jCF70b4Mx0zasKvF3jdvK6DbKORD5skr092zAHCZsedEtOtfKwjovfjIZspMPAdYUlWmN6lgxVTAM1qoXsmoZ00rroso34u7woNh9ZctJPcWvUlqphzRqnrg@dBfBCa2dM076R1rKtd/mrJ0BqpkyYSmaGNULMISp4TUCqTdoribTb5cyUJ2H6M9IHlErzgaLT9JizmpeYWCxUVSP1l35G@gO0JdnO6PfLnElxJC@JxS@9Wq0@nZ2cHvuOskVkPFKjAoe5@Bu136QPbi@F3ldvFE1VP0etlW6Qb@BUJ22WZczKPyH/B8@HxiL9/gT6EuS9mG9puUTUWFyeAQ)

Comment: `test al, 1/jnz` => `inc eax/jp`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
2XĿȮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//MljEv8iuCv8xxL/huZvigJz/)

Function submission. There are two functions defined in the above code; the one being submitted is `1Ŀ`, with `2Ŀ` being a helper function. Outputs strings of `2` to standard output (the TIO link has a footer to suppress implicit output of the function's return value, because that isn't part of the output).

### Explanation

Jelly isn't very good at this challenge, as golfing languages go, but I managed to beat the existing Jelly answer by one byte.

The function `1Ŀ` is defined as `2XĿȮ`. `2X` generates a random number, either 1 or 2. Then `Ŀ` runs the function with that number – this is either a recursive call if 1 was chosen as the random number, or a call to `2Ŀ` if 2 was chosen. Finally, it produces output (`Ȯ`) – the output will always be 2 because that's the argument implicitly chosen for the function calls. If `1Ŀ` calls itself many times recursively, it'll output from every recursive level, which is what produces a random-length string of 2s.

The function `2Ŀ` is defined with zero-length source code, and returns its input (i.e. the 2 that it was provided as input when called by `1Ŀ`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 6 bytes

```
?+`$
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3147QYWr4v9/AA) Outputs an average of 1 `x`. Explanation: The `?` causes the loop created by `+` to run with a geometric distribution with a mean of `1`. Each iteration of the loop appends an `x` to current value, which is then output when the loop terminates.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
=REPT(1,1/RAND())
```

*-2 bytes excluding 0 length string*

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnjjhRKitqGW9lHsZ?e=bilhEw)

Comment: "You may choose whether to include the empty string as a possible output", so I think you can shave that ```-1```...

Comment: It was right there and I missed it.  Doh!

Comment: You can shave off 1 byte by switching Excel language to Polish: `=POWT(1,1/LOS())`.

Comment: @pajonk And would Reverse Polish be `= 1 1 LOS / POWT`?

Comment: @Neil My HP 12C salutes you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
f=do n<-randomIO;putStr"x";if n then pure()else f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK802JV8hz0a3CMz19LcuKC0JLilSqlCyzkxTyFMoyUjNUygoLUrV0EzNKU5VSPufm5iZZ5v2HwA)

- Saved 5 thanks to @pxeger suggestions to use pure instead of return and semicolons;

Comment: `return` can be `pure`, and you can smush the whole `do` block onto one line using semicolons, for -5 bytes in total: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK802JV8hz0a3CMz19LcuKC0JLilSqlCyzkxTyFMoyUjNUygoLUrV0EzNKU5VSPufm5iZZ5v2HwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks @pxeger I forgot to use ; .. I was struggling to find an alternative to return, I was sure there were some. I also read in some docs of a do block similar to list comprehension syntax but not sure if is just a proposal or what.. Forgot where it was unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

## [MSX-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX_BASIC), 28 bytes

```
1IFRND(-TIME)<.9THEN?1:GOTO1
```

- `RND` with a negative value gets the first value from the pseudo-random sequence whose seed is the passed value.
- `TIME` is a system 16 bit variable that increases continuously (and goes back to 0 on overflow) at 50 or 60Hz.
- `?` is a convenient shortcut for `PRINT`.

Answer (score 2):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), 23 bytes

```
DOREADOUT#0DO%9TRYAGAIN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FP8jV0cU/NETZwMVf1TIkKNLR3dHT7/9/AA)

Prints a nonempty string of underscores separated by triple newlines, running a loop that continues 9% of the time ([insert another digit if you want better odds](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FP8jV0cU/NETZwMVf1dIgJCjS0d3R0@//fwA)).

Answer (score 2):

### C - 76 Bytes

```
j;main(i){for(;j++<2+rand()%10;puts(""))for(i=0;i++<1+rand()%10;printf("x"));}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
j;

main(i)
{
    for(; j++ < 2 + rand() % 10; puts(""))
        for(i = 0; i++ < 1 + rand() % 10; printf("x"));

}
```

**Explanation**

A simple but complete program that prints a random number of strings of character 'x' of indeterminate length.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
2' e+EUw.n$@t'xoK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99IXSFV2zW0XC9PxaFEvSLf@/9/AA)

My first Alice attempt, I'm keen to see what can be made shorter!

### Explanations:

```
2' e+E              Pushes max int on the stack 2^(32-1)
      U             Random between max int and 0
       w.n$@     K  While the top of the stack is not 0
            t       -1 to the top of the stack
             'x     Pushes x on the stack
               o    Prints the top of the stack as a character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 33 <s>34</s> bytes

```
END{for(srand();rand();)print"x"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lurgoMS9FQ9O6PCMzJ1UDwtEsKMrMK1GqUKr9/x8A)

It is possible for awk's `rand()` to return 0, but very unlikely.

Thanks to Marius_Couet for the byte!

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

With "include the empty string as a possible output".

```php
while(0<$r=rand(0,100)/10){echo $r<0.1?'':str_repeat('p',round($r))."\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1DGxUimyLEvNSNAx0DA0MNPUNDTSrU5Mz8hVUimwM9Azt1dWtikuK4otSC1ITSzTUC9R1ivJLgcpVijQ19ZRi8pSsa///BwA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 52 bytes

```php
while(0<$r=rand(0,9)){echo str_repeat('p',$r)."\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1DGxUimyLEvNSNAx0LDU1q1OTM/IVikuK4otSC1ITSzTUC9R1VIo09ZRi8pSsa///BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```perl
say while.9>rand
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhPCMzJ1XP0q4oMS/l//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Saved two bytes by making the unary character a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```
import random;randomize();while rand(1)<1:echo 1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3DTJzC_KLShSKEvNS8nOtIVRmVaqGpnV5RmZOKlhCw1DTxtAqNTkjX8EQog-qHWYMAA)

This program has a newline as a separator and a `'1'` as the character. `wc -c` was utilized to count the number of bytes.
I am reasonably certain this is optimal for Nim; I therefore will offer a bounty of 50 rep to the person who outgolfs it.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 20 bytes

```
∇X←P
X←⍬
X,←'x'
→?4∇
```

The output strings are usually extremely short, but hypothetically they could be any length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```rkt
(do()((>(random).5))(print 1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY6xDsIwDET3foUlFntBdGCqxMIPIFaEUGhdGpHYKEnVzy9O@QPGu3enu@T6N5d1F5y8IG2iaboOzhojSwGdC5SJYdQQdPEWCl4Y/AiiRjgX82rhOkvekr0ODO0Bio@c9w2OmgBvD8BkE5XQnVYcFAnxVM1BI@2PRPhJ3hZbovWfA5fazuBAePllnlwWZgF2/QRpFjtjrCKb@AI)

### Explanation

Creates a `do` loop that will only run if the `random`ly generated number is less than `.5`. The first argument of the `do` loop are the local variables and/or iterators. The second argument is the `stop?-expr`. If this argument returns true (`#t`), the loop will stop. Otherwise the body of the loop will be run.

```rkt
(do () ((> (random) .5))
  (print 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fish](https://fishshell.com/), 31 bytes

```
while [ (random) = 0 ];echo;end
```

This uses the newline (U+000A) as the unary character. `random` returns any value from 0-32768 without arguments, so on most runs this will echo nothing. However, it is *technically* possible for this to echo an unlimited number of characters, just not very likely

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 4 bytes

```
?@#.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/395BWe//fwA)

### Explanation

The `?` instruction sends the program counter (PC) in a random direction. If the PC goes right, it hits the `@` instruction, which terminates the program. If it goes up or down, it makes a new random choice. If it goes left, it hits the `.` instruction, which pops the top of the stack and prints it as an integer. There is no stack underflow in Befunge (or at least not in the implementation tio uses), so the value popped is the default value, zero (`0`). So the program prints `0`, with a single space ( ) as a separator. The bridge command `#` makes sure that another random choice will occur and the `@` isn't immediately triggered.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 20 bytes

Anonymous immediate window function that outputs a sequence of newline literals of random length to the immediate window console.

```vb
While(rnd>.5):?:Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 31 bytes

```bash
while(($RANDOM));do echo 1;done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVQ0MlyNHPxd9XU9M6JV8hNTkjX8EQyMpL/f8fAA)

Comment: This doesn't output anything longer than 32767, does it?

Comment: @pxeger Yes, it does.

Comment: So then it's an invalid answer. Read the question again: it needs to be possible to output strings of any arbitrary length

Comment: @pxeger One question, why your code in Pure Zsh is valid? It doesn't output anything longer than 32767 as well, does it?

Comment: No, mine doesn't just loop `$RANDOM` times; it's a while loop - each time it loops, it checks if `$RANDOM` is zero, and if so, stops the loop. So it's possible for it to loop more than that many times, if `$RANDOM` takes 32769 or more iterations before reaching zero

Comment: @pxeger oh ... i got it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Emmental](https://github.com/catseye/Emmental), 20 bytes

When the computer runs out of stack space it will crash.

```
;#58:#46#35#63#!#1#?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83NTc0rScz5/99a2dTCStnETNnYVNnMWFlR2VDZ/v9/AA)
When the computer runs out of stack space it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/flags.md)

```
(¢TLɼ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyzUOLQrxOblnSXFScjFUDCYHAA)

##### Explanation

```python
(      # loop while the following is true:
 ¢     #  print a 0 without a trailing newline
  TL   #  push the range [1..10]
    ɼ  #  choose a random item from that list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue) 17 bytes

```
E::=
E::=E*
::=
E
```

On the interpreter that I use, it is randoms

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 8 bytes

```
1?[01?]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/QPtrA0D624P9/AA)

Pushes the number 1 onto the stack a random number of times then exits.  The accumulated numbers are printed automatically with a space between them.  The probabilities favor small (or zero) numbers, but there's a non-zero change of any length output.

```
1?        - Push "1" on the stack, replace with 0|1 randomly
  [   ]   - Loop while the top of the stack is non-zero
   01?    - Push "0 1", pop them and push 0|1 randomly
       p  - Pop the "0" that ended the loop off the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Volatile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Volatile), 7 bytes

```
~(:-.~)
```

Assumes that the `.` instruction is present in the interpreter. Prints a random length of `0` characters. Empty string is possible. Zeroes may be separated by another character, depending on the implementation you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
jot 19 | mawk 'NF+=int(rand()*19)' OFS=x
```

---

```
1xxxxxxx
2xxxxxxxxxx
3xxxxx
4
5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
6xxxxxxxxx
7xxxxxxx
8xxxxx
9xxxxxxxxx
10xxxxxx
11xxx
12xxxxx
13xxxxxxxx
14x
15xxxxxxxxx
16xxxxxxxx
17xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
18xxxxx
19
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 22 bytes

Function that outputs a sequence of newline literals of random length.

```vb
While(ran()>.5):?:Wend
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP5vr6Srq1CSkVmsUJZZXJqYk1mVWqyQmJRflqqQX1pSUFqi9D88IzMnVaMoMU9D007PVNPK3io8NS8Fu86k1Jz8cphO6/8A)