# Output / Convert to unary number

Tags: code-golf

Your task is it to output a number as a unary string. You get the number of a  non-negative integer input in the range of 0 - 2'000'000'000.

Rules

- You can choose any character for the digit you like. But it has to be the same everywhere and for every input.
- Output a unary string by outputting this character N times. N is the input.
- Input range is 0 - 2'000'000'000 (inclusive)
- A input of 0 result in a empty string except the optional starting and ending characters.
- You may or may not add optional starting and ending characters at the start and/or end, for example a newline character or `[` and `]`. If you do, all outputs (including of the input 0) must have one. This characters are different from the the character for the digit you have chosen.
- Input integer is given as decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary number, whatever is convenient for you.
- You are free to use a pattern of multiple characters for a single digit. But it has to be the same pattern for all digits and for every input.
- Digit grouping is optional. If you use it, the group size has to be constant and the separation character has to be the same everywhere.
- Your program should finish in less than 4h on a modern desktop CPU with 4 GB of free RAM, for any valid input.
- Output is a string or stream of characters.

Examples / test cases:

```
Input  ->  Output

./yourProgram 1  -> 1
./yourProgram 12 -> 111111111111
./yourProgram 0  -> 
./yourProgram 2000000000 | tr -d -c '1' | wc -c -> 2000000000
./yourProgram 32 -> 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Non-golf example program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for i in range( int(sys.argv[1]) ):
  print("1", end='')
```

This is `code-golf`, so the shortest code wins.

Related but they have significant differences:

- [Output a random unary string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243525/output-a-random-unary-string)
- [Parse a list of signed unary numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150775/parse-a-list-of-signed-unary-numbers)
- [Brainf**k to Unary and Back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52712/brainfk-to-unary-and-back)

Comment: Can I output a list of unary digits?

Comment: I mean outputting a list like [1,1,1] rather than a string like "111"

Comment: @noodleman You can output the string "[1,1,1]" but it has to be a string or some other form of character stream. Not some internal data structure.

Comment: What do you mean by “internal data structure”? I meant outputting a list of unary digits, rather than say a list of characters which is basically what a string is.

Comment: @noodleman internal data structures of a object that doesn't have the output as one char after the next in memory but uses some internal pointer magic behind de scenes (as it is done in high level languages like Python or JavaScript) or only generates the output at demand.

Comment: Just to confirm: a function that *returns* a string (and doesn't output anything) is ok, right?

Comment: @TheThonnu I would prefer standalone programs/scripts. But gave up on that, because people don't like that for some reason. So it is ok.

Comment: Can the separator be more than one character? e.g. `1, 1, 1` instead of `1,1,1`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Why are you arbitrarily overriding default output methods? [generators](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753) [lists](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17167) [definition of a list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/what-is-a-list) Also, if this is a clarification, it should be an edit, not buried in the comments.

Comment: In particular, this unfairly disadvantages languages like Haskell where the default string type is a lazy linked list.

Comment: I wonder which answers did actually test the runtime for the big number edge case.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Yes. Some answers use that (in particular C where some garbage is printed for every digit).

Comment: @SuperStormer A linked list sounds like a high memory usage anyway. Can you store a string with the memory size of 2 bytes per character or less?

Comment: It finishes in 52 seconds and well under the memory limit on my machine.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 11 bytes

```python
'0'.__mul__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX91AXS8@Prc0Jz7@f0FRZl6JRpqGqabmfwA)

Note: `0` could be any other character. Function returning a string.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
def f(n):print('0'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0/TqqAoM69EQ91AXStP83@ahqnmfwA)

Function which prints the string.

Comment: Very clever usage of python magic functions

Answer (score 7):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)’s Type System, 62 bytes

```typescript
type U<N,L extends 1[]=[]>=L extends{length:N}?L:U<N,[...L,1]>
```

[Try it at the TypeScript Playground!](https://tsplay.dev/wE8Q2W)

Type definition taking a generic integer type and recursively appending 1 to a tuple type until its length is the integer type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot handle more than 999 (at least at the playground) I've run into TS limitations many times in real code, so it's the first thing I've checked with a little hope that something has changed. :(

Comment: @Nikolay Yep, that's the recursion limit for tail-recursive TS types. For non tail-recursive types it's only 50. You can make tuple types that are much longer (I want to say 9,999 elements?) so in theory you could subtract 999 and append `U<999>` but I can't think of a way to do that subtraction and to check if the number is too big without either A. using unary, which won't work because the number is too big; or B. implementing math based on digit lists, which sounds like hell and also way overkill for this.

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 1 byte

```
Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENT0/r/fzPL/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal prints a number as a number of `-`, `|`, `/` or `\` symbols depending on the direction of the pivot, the default being horizontal.

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 4 bytes

```perl6
1 x*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb731ChQuu/NVdxYqVCmoahgeZ/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 12 bytes

```rust
|a|vec![0;a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMHGtDyF3MTMPA1Nheqc1BKFNNulpSVpuhZraxJrylKTFaMNrBNjrSFiewqKMvNKcvIUNZSqrexrlXQU0jQsDAw0Na25uGohShYsgNAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTUmZmxhZ3M9)

Uses a space as the character.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
I
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJJIiwiIiwiNSJd)

Same as above.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-O3`, 24 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@12431234123412341234123](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59900/12431234123412341234123)*

```c
f(n){n&&puts(f)+f(n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk9NraC0pFgjTVMbyNc11LSu/Z@ZV8KVm5iZp1GWn5miyVXNlaZhqmnNVfv/X3JaTmJ68X9df2MA)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42 bytes

*Full program, input from stdin*

```c
main(n){printf("%.*d",n,!scanf("%d",&n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zuqAoM68kTUNJVU8rRUknT0exODkxD8QH8tTyNDWta///NwUA)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-m32`, 44 bytes

*Full program, input as command line argument*

```c
*p;main(n,v){printf("%.*d",atoi(1[p=v]),0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@rwDo3MTNPI0@nTLO6oCgzryRNQ0lVTytFSSexJD9TwzC6wLYsVlPHQNO69v///yb/ktNyEtOL/@vmGhsBAA)

Comment: For the recursive variant, I get a stack overflow when the input is too high. Can you avoid that?

Comment: `f(n){while(n--)puts(f);}`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 if you enable optimizations gcc will recognize the tail recursion

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 5 bytes

```
.+
$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRev/fzNLAA) Explanation: Outputs `1` repeated by the input count, with a trailing newline.

For Retina 1, remove the `$`, and then the program outputs `_` repeated by the input count, without a trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 21 bytes

```lua
print(('0'):rep(...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ91AXdOqKLVAQ09PT1Pz////pgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 4 bytes

```
#&LF
```

Uses linefeed as the character. The large test case will not work on ATO, but `100 timex '# f 2000000000'` yields an average of 0.421414 seconds.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxRFkNxrx5WJMrNTkjX0FdFztQh0inKRgSq86IKIUaaQoGmgq6ViAdCn5Oegop-anFCpklCrmJJckZ9gp5-XpEWmhsBPHKggUQGgA)

```
#&LF
#     NB. copy
 &LF  NB. bond LF as the right argument
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
(}?@_.)<!>*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/1@j1t4hXk/TRtFOS/3/f0MDAwA)

Layed out

```
   ( } ?
  @ _ . )
 < ! > * '
  . . . .
   . . .
```

#### Explanation

`(}?` some irrelevant operations initially, then get the input

`<` branch, if 0 go to `@` and terminate, otherwise point the IP southeast

`(_` decrement the input cell and redirect the IP northeast

`}*)!` move the MP to the cell to the right, set that cell to 1 and print that out

`_>` redirect the IP back east

`*'` irrelevant operation, then move the MP back to the input cell

this then loops back to the branch command

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with 0.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Fixed it so that it works for 0 now and also saved 2 bytes in the process :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 21 bytes

`x=>new String('a',x);`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0/D4IwEMVn@yneRglVUccCi4mTm4MDYTCk4EXTmraoCeGz1/rvll/uvXf3WjdvHYXdoFsUpL2A85Z0X6FDifAsK60eOHw0npwS8UxluJ8szCX63g5KsvdK@jZ4F6V3vG4wYiWwWgvkApsITBLL5Tr/D@uMBY@FoHiUy4ji92SxV7r3Z4kso5SNbLY12pmrWhwtebUnrXjHv9GamjSVbAov)

My first time writing an answer here!

Comment: -1 byte by dropping the semicolon (just move it to the footer on TIO)

Comment: @SuperStormer is that accepted? I looked through some other C# solutions, I think most finish with a semicolon.

Comment: Well, [this works](https://tio.run/##NY09D4IwGIRn@yvejTZUvhwLLCZObA4OhIGQqm80rWmLkhB@ey1@3PLkLrm7wW4Hi977Z29A36ACZ0YpyGpRPUZnQ6TkC9oOZsg55AWHjMMuABYBaVpkf5GzNkBROcBQykRA@RtJGqku7iogjpGRmWz2Wll9l8nJoJMNKkkpPYxqKEOdW2dQXWpGp6pev48fT6M@4hNjjH43W@wYE2Txbw "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") so I would say yes. The `;` doesn't appear to be part of the actual function definition, based on my limited understanding.

Comment: @SuperStormer: But can you write other code after it without a `;`?  Imagine you're writing a C# program, and want to use this definition as part of it instead of inlining the definition at every use-case.  You need to count all the bytes necessary for the statement that defines the lambda or function, that come between other source lines of your program.  (Or without actual newlines since you can put everything on one line.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Citing precedent: [Should function literals be allowed when a function is asked for?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501)

Comment: @SuperStormer: Where does that meta Q&A say anything about omitting semicolons?  For C-like languages, it just says lambdas are allowed instead of full function definitions (which is widely agreed upon).

Comment: Isn't `x=>new String('a',x)` a valid anymous function literal?

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10 bytes

<sup>Hover over any symbol to see what it does</sup>

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTo/ITsxLTFuISIsImlucHV0IjoiMTIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIn0=)

Comment: Unfortunately this method of explanation is useless on my iPhone.

Comment: @noodleman you should be able to long press a symbol to see the title on mobile

Comment: It just selects all the text.

Comment: This runs at about 1 character per second on my computer (with a 3900X). Maybe it is just the online interpreter. Can it finish in the required time on a native interpreter or compiled program?

Comment: It will be a lot faster on TIO

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 15 bytes

```javascript
n=>"".padEnd(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k5JSa8gMcU1L0UjT/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoappuZ/AA)

Returns the string. Uses a space as the character.

This might not be allowed, but for **9 bytes**

```javascript
"".padEnd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@19JSa8gMcU1L@V/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGml5yYk6OhpKSjoKppuZ/AA)

*-1 from both thanks to @Arnauld*

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
n=>print("".padEnd(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9auoCgzr0RDSUmvIDHFNS9FI09T83@ahqnmfwA)

Prints the string.

Comment: I think [using spaces is allowed](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k5JSa8gMcU1L0UjT/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoappuZ/AA)?

Comment: @Arnauld great idea, thanks!

Comment: I think that `"".padEnd` is a valid answer itself, you don't need to wrap it

Comment: @Samathingamajig no, unfortunately that doesn't work in JS - see [here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfSUmvIDHFNS/lf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGqabmfwA)

Comment: If you look at the top answer, which is Python, it is just `"0".__mul__`. You're just providing the built-in for this. You just need to provide a function, and `"".padEnd` is a function. How you call it is outside the scope of this challenge. So, just `"".padEnd` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel in Python, you can assign `"0".__mul__` to a variable. On JavaScript, you can't assign `"".padEnd` to a variable.

Comment: @TheThonnu You can, but you have to use `.call` or `.apply` on it. But it doesn't matter: it's a function. A function is acceptable.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel idk, I'll ask in TNB

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64030599#64030599). It seems that just `"".padEnd` is invalid.

Comment: @TheThonnu Well, I guess I was wrong then. However, they did miss the point I was making, but that's just details.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 11 bytes

```java
"1"::repeat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BSsRADIbvfYqwpynowJ6EretREPTUo3iI3VjSnabDTLrbRfbZ6xSnKphL8idfkr/DE952h@PMvR@CQpe0HZWdrRsUoVAV/yYfozTKg9jHXFRF4cd3xw00DmOEF2SBzwJS5H5U1JROAx@gT1NTa2BpX98AQxvLDC@x3rx/EqWWwg18ow@wvIX9vNludrtAnlDn6mctu4UIexA6r9rUl6jUW5byl2VRmBKXP1iPIVISJlqhSZ9ZyJR/@HxjGNX6ZEWdmMWLRe/dxUwrei2u890X)

Comment: I think that `"1".repeat` would be a valid answer to this

Comment: @Samathingamajig No, it has to be a function, but `"1"::repeat` works; a method reference instead of a lambda expression. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 15 bytes

```arturo
$=>[repeat"1"&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?OMx7fz)

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 8 bytes

```
"1"*.+""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/JUElLT1tJ6f9/AwA)

Answer (score 3):

### Pascal, 96 characters

```pascal
program u(input,output);var i:integer;begin read(i);while i>0 do begin write('');i≔i−1 end end.
```

Necessary implementation characteristics:
The value of `maxInt` must be ≥ 2000000000.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/ M \1*.n$@9ot
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fwVchxlBLL0/FwTK/hOv///9GBgYA)

The new line at the end of the code is required
Uses tab as the output character

```
/ M \1*.n$@9ot    # Full program
/ M \1*           # Reads one argument as a string and multiply it by 1, this is our loop counter
       .n$@       # Stop if the counter is down to 0
           9o     # Output a <tab>
             t    # Decrement the counter
                  # Goes back to the beginning of the line
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler*

```
(`replicate`'a')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWUOqmUm5iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKgkZCUWpBTmZyYklqgnqiuqaCoQFUA1QHAA)

On my machine, it finished in 48.68 seconds and had a max RSS of 4656 kb, well under the time and memory limits.

Comment: (\`replicate\`'a') works at 16 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
$×
```

Uses character `1`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f5fD0//8NjQE)

```
Î×
```

Uses character `0`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cN/h6f//GxoDAA)

```
°¦
```

Uses character `0` as well.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IZDy/7/NzQGAA)

```
õú
```

Uses a space as character.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NbDu/7/NzQGAA)

If different multiple output-characters would have been allowed, it could be 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) with:

```
∍
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UUfv//@GxgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
$   # Push 1 and the input-integer
 ×  # Repeat the 1 the input amount of times as string
    # (which is output implicitly as result)

Î   # Push 0 and the input-integer
 ×  # Repeat the 0 the input amount of times as string
    # (which is output implicitly as result)

°   # Push 10 to the power of the (implicit) input-integer
 ¦  # Remove the leading 1 so only the 0s remain
    # (which is output implicitly as result)

õ   # Push an empty string ""
 ú  # Pad it with the (implicit) input-integer amount of leading spaces
    # (which is output implicitly as result)

∍   # Extend/shorten the (implicit) input to a length of the (implicit) input-integer
    # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `If multiple output-characters would have been allowed, it could be 1 byte with:` it is: `You are free to use a pattern of multiple characters for a single digit` But it has to be the same for every input which `∍` doesn't do.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 made a minor clarification to the explanation, but it's indeed invalid, hence the 2 byte solutions. :)

Comment: If you could use a different digit composed of multiple characters for each input, you can cheat by always output `N` times (except when the input is 0) the same character where `N` is the product of all primes between 1 and 2000000000. A digit is then `M` times this character where `M` is `N/<input>`. Well, if the program is fast enough which is maybe not the case for a `N` this large. A smaller example: Always output 30 times `A`. If the input is 1, a single digit has 30 times `A` in it, if the input is 2, a digit has 15 times `A` in it, if it is 3, a digit has 10 times `A` in it, ...

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, 13 bytes (with calling other programs)

```
yes|head -n$1
```

###### Explanation

`yes` prints lines with the content `yes`. `head -n` will filter for the first n lines, n is given with `$1`.
The line with `yes` is used as digit.

### Pure Bash, 29 <s>34</s> bytes

```
for((i=$1;0<i;i--));do [;done
```

###### Explanation

The `for((i=$1;0<i;i--))` will do the commands between `do` and `done` `$1` times. `[` is a builtin bash command that expects a test and a `]`, which isn't provided, so it prints a error message every time. The error message is used as digit.

I tried also this one:

```
$1||pwd;$1||0 $(($1-1))
```

Which works almost when the script is named 0 and in the current `$PATH`. But it fails with large inputs, so not a working solution.

###### Explanation

The `||` means, if that on the left side fails, try that on the right side instead (till the end of the line or `;`). If it doesn't fail ignore the part on the right side. If there is nothing on the left side, the right is also ignored.

This tries to call program `$1`, i.e. the first parameter provided.  Since the script is named `0`, it will work with the input `0`. so it calls itself without any argument. And then, when it runs without an argument, `$1` will expands to nothing, which means do nothing and ignore the part right of `||`.

If the parameter `$1` is a `number>0`, it will fail to execute a program because there is no program with that name. This means a error message is printed to `stderr`, which we ignore, and then the right side of `||` is executed.

The `$1||pwd;` part means: If program `$1` is not valid, i.e. `$1` is a number above `0`, it calls `pwd`. `pwd` outputs something to `stdout` and it shouldn't change. So we can use it as a non-changing digit. The `$1||0 $(($1-1))` part means: If program `$1` is not valid, call `0` / itself with the parameter `$(($1-1))`. `$(($1-1))` means 1 subtracted from `$1`.

It fails with large input because it recursively calls itself and so a new process starts. But i can't create 2'000'000'000 processes on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

## x86 / x86-64 machine-code, 7 bytes, as fast as memset

Just a function, not a full program, so we only need to `memset(buf, '1', n)` + append a terminating 0 to make an implicit-length C-style string in the buffer the caller supplies, of size `n+1` or larger.

This could be called from C in the x86-64 System V calling convention as `void to_unary(char *dst, int dummy, int dummy, size_t n)`.  Size is limited only by address-space limits.

```
machine code | NASM source

              ; RDI or ES:EDI = output buffer of size n
              ; RCX or ECX = n
              to_unary:
 B031           mov al, '1'
 F3AA           rep stosb
 880F           mov byte [rdi], cl    ; RCX was zeroed by rep stos
 C3             ret
```

[`stos` stores and *then* increments](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stos:stosb:stosw:stosd:stosq), so it leaves RDI pointing after the last byte it stored.  We depend on the calling convention for DF=0 (increment not decrement), as is normal for all mainstream 32 and 64-bit calling conventions.

The same machine code bytes will do the same thing in 32-bit mode.

At first I was going to use `dec eax` / `stosb` for the terminator, with `1` instead of `'1'` as the unary digit "character".  This would be 2 bytes in 32-bit mode only.  But then I realized a `mov` store wouldn't need a displacement in the addressing mode, and that we had `cl`=0.

---

For an explicit-length-string version using separate pointer+length, we could return the input length after filling the input buffer (also leaving a pointer to the end in RDI).  This would take the same total machine-code size: `push rcx` to start, `pop rax` at the end, instead of `mov [rdi], cl`.

---

**If the buffer is large and aligned, speed on typical modern CPUs, especially with the [ERMSB feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy), is basically as fast as typical libc memset, at least on Intel maybe not AMD.**

On a typical desktop, single-core memory bandwidth is usually close to maxing out the memory controllers.  ([Much lower per-core bandwidth on many-core Xeons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug).)  Slower with page faults on the first access to newly allocated RAM, but this runs about as fast as it's possible for a single thread to go (for large aligned buffers), except by playing virtual memory tricks to map a range of virtual pages to the same memsetted page of '1's.  With a misaligned buffer it's still probably under a second to fill 2GB.  For small `n`, [microcode startup overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902068/what-setup-does-rep-do) dominates, even on CPUs with the "fast-short-rep" feature.  AMD CPUs may have slower `rep stos`, but even storing 1 byte per clock cycle would be way faster than the 4 hour requirement needs.

Comment: Does it reserve the buffer? If not, from where do you get it? Or will it cause a Segment Fault when you run it?

Comment: @12431234: The caller passes it a pointer to a buffer for it to store the output string in.  This is one of a couple normal ways for C functions to produce array output, same for assembly.  (Others being to `malloc` new memory).  If the caller passes it a bad pointer, that's a bug in the caller.  I looked through [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942) but that linked answer is the only one I found that seems related to whether this is an allowed output method, but I've used it before in many other challenges where the output is an array.

Comment: I think this answer is more relevant for that: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8511/59900 I see that this are the default Input/Output. (if you ask me, the default should only be fully runnable programs). The problem in this question is that allocating the correct amount of memory is already most of the task. When you use a 0-byte as digit, you can even `mmap` or `calloc()` enough bytes and set the address one byte after the last digit to 1 (or a different value) and don't have to set any other byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [jot(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot(1)), 10 bytes

```sh
jot -b1 $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Pyu/REE3yVBBxfB/LVeagqlCjUJRsYJuugGQY2yEzDM1MDAA8suTFXRzuJTTFIwMYAAm@h8A)

Outputs a stream of `1`s separated by newlines. TIO times out doing the 2 billion case, but it takes just 4 minutes on my Intel Mac

```sh
$ time jot -b 1 2000000000|wc -l
 2000000000
jot -b 1 2000000000  243.40s user 0.52s system 99% cpu 4:04.24 total
wc -l  2.61s user 1.70s system 1% cpu 4:04.24 total
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 9 <s>15</s> <s>17</s> bytes

```
<,7_@#:+&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30bHPN5B2Upb7f9/I0NzAA)

This program is pretty simple. It gets a number as input, then it decrements it by adding `-1`. `-1` is the value returned when there is no input left, so I'm able to just use one `&` symbol to get the numbers I need and just continue adding the current value and `-1` to decrement. Each time the number is decremented, the program checks if it is `0`, and if it is, it quits. I did this by using a bridge (`#`) to skip over the stop command (`@`) and the go backward to the `@` if the value is `0` using a horizontal if `_`. Previous versions of my program weren't linear, but rather 2d, so the control was taking up a lot of space. The bridge command allowed me to keep control linear. The program starts with a `<` to make the program go backwards, this is because the horizontal if statement `_` goes right if `0`, but I need it to go left, so I reversed the whole program because that's easier than reversing it's input.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

*Full program, takes 1 argument*

```c
main(a,v)int**v;{for(a=atoi(v[1]);a--;puts(*v));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1GnTDMzr0RLq8y6Oi2/SCPRNrEkP1OjLNowVtM6UVfXuqC0pFhDq0xT07r2////hgYA)

Comment: `puts(v)` may work as well (not very reliable but reliable enough. It depends on the ASLR. Most runs works => good enough).

Comment: I originally had `f(n){while(n--)puts(f);}` but then saw that function was already submitted, so I pivoted to this. `puts(v)` will vary based on the input/run, so I decided to go with `puts(*v)`. Maybe I was too strict with the rules on this one.

Comment: Leave it up there, I don't care. I'll also note that `f(n){for(;n--;)puts(f);)` is the same length.

Comment: If you creative about the input specification, this will also work: `main(a,v)int**v;{for(a=*v[1];a--;puts(*v));}` On my machine, to input 0 use `./a.out '' '' '' ''`, To input 32 `./a.out ' ' '' '' ''`. 8224 `./a.out '  ' '' '' ''` for 2097184 use `./a.out ' ' ' ' '' ''` for 8192 `./a.out '' ' ' '' ''`. Not sure how to escape `'\x01'` in bash but that is a problem of bash not the program.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 31 bytes

```swift
{.init(repeating:"1",count:$0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQZqWg4ZlXoqmga6cQXFKUmZeuYPu/Wi8zL7NEoyi1IDWxBChkpWSopJOcX5pXYqVioFn7vwCorkQjTcPIQFPzPwA) A bit more verbose than some, but hopefully clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 9 bytes

```ruby
->n{?1*n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhYrde3yqu0NtfJqIfxVBaUlxQpu0YZGsRCBBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 2):

**As a whole program:**

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```fs
[<EntryPoint>]let m a=[for _ in 1..(int(Seq.head a))->printf"1"];0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/P9rGNa@kqDIgPzOvxC42J7VEIVch0TY6Lb9IIV4hM0/BUE9PAyilEZxaqJeRmpiikKipqWtXUAQUS1MyVIq1Nvj//7@hEQA)

---

**As a function:**

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 33 bytes

```fs
fun a->[for _ in 1..a->printf"1"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv1vaMRVY/c/rTRPIVHXLjotv0ghXiEzT8FQTw/ILyjKzCtJUzJUiv3/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Matlab], 9 bytes

```
ones(1,n)
```

ones generates mxn matrixes of 1s

---

## [Matlab], 16 bytes

second version upon remarks in the comments

```
s=@(n) ones(1,n)
```

anonymous function that generates mxn matrixes of 1s

Comment: Taking input through a variable (like `n`) isn't allowed. You'll need to turn this into a function or full program.

Comment: i intended it as 'n' is already defined in the workspace and this is a command window call

Comment: Although that makes sense for some languages like Matlab, it's unfortunately [still disallowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/79857).

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 26 bytes

```
@for/l %i in (1,1,%1)do cd
```

The `@` is needed to prevent unwanted echo of the `for` command, but echo of the `cd` command is per-iteration anyway so no `@` is needed. The four spaces are needed so that the code will parse correctly.

Comment: `You may or may not add optional starting and ending characters at the start and/or end` Couldn't you remove the `@`? I can't test it.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 It would repeat the `cd` an extra time, which would make the answer invalid.

Answer (score 2):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 17 bytes

This creates an anonymous anonymous function that returns the expected result:

```
fn($x)=>&tb($x,1)
```

This is a full program that does the same thing, but outputs it (also 17 bytes):

```
out&tb($argv[0]1)
```

---

### How does it work?

This runs the function `&tb`, which is an alias to `&tobase`.

It takes the number and the base.
It relies on JavaScript's [`Number.prototype.toString(radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#parameters) with a special case to handle unary (where it just outputs 1s).

---

### Ungolfed

Ungolfing both versions at the same time.

All examples here are executable on their own, and take a JSON array as input, with the value you wish.
This isn't a limitation of the program at all - it's just how you pass values to the compiler to populate the `$argv` variable.

All examples will be written with `&tobase` for clarity.

#### Code-like

```
// Anonymous function - assigned to $fn
$fn = fn($x) => &tobase($x, 1);
// Calls the function and outputs the result
echo call $fn(argv[0], 1);


// Full program
echo &tobase($argv[0], 1);
```

#### Plain-English-like

```
// Anonymous function - assigned to $fn
Set the variable $fn to an anonymous function with argument $x
Begin.
    Return the result of calling the function &tobase with the arguments $x, 1.
End.

// Calls the function and outputs the result
Display the result of calling the variable $fn with the arguments $argv[0], 1.


// Full program
Display the result of calling the function &tobase with the arguments $argv[0], 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [D](https://www.dlang.org), 43 bytes

```
(int x){import std;return"1".replicate(x);}
```

not sure if I can make it much shorter. I can't just do a short lambda (`x=>...`) because it requires `replicate` from `std.array`. I tried doing some stuff with `iota` and `map` but that resulted in 4 bytes longer than this simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile) (C version), 6 bytes

`{[9#)}`

prints n tabs

Running the program with input `2000000000` takes a bit over 2 minutes and consumes about 150kBit of memory (when using the debug build of the interpreter) so the program is well withing the time and memory limits.

[Interpreter](https://github.com/bsoelch/ForWhile)

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=e1s5Iyl9CgoxJAoKMTAgMUA_)
Note that the online interpreter does not satisfy the efficiency requirements

## Explanation

```
{    } anonymous procedure
 [  )  repeat n times
  9#   print tab
```

calling the procedure

```
{[9#)} 1$  store procedure at address 1
2000000000 1@? call procedure with argument `2000000000`
```

---

## ForWhile, 26 bytes

`99[_48-:0<!:[.'2*+1]).[9#)`

Full program, reads binary integer from standard input

```
99[                 )       \ repeat up to 99 times
   _                        \ get a byte from standard input
    48-                     \ subtract char-code of 0
       :0<!:[      ]        \ if value is non-negative
             .    1         \ temporarily remove condition from stack
              '2*+          \ duplicate current value and add new bit
                    ).      \ break loop if last character was less than 48
                      [9#)  \ print tab n times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 22 bytes (2×11=22 codels)

```
tabrjcdskcK  a?kqak kk
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJwdikkKgDAUQ--SdQp-J2yvUroQrSA4QXUl3t3fJpuX4cV0zhHO-4rSU1rWHCgdpWZDm8kGelGy5TBo2WYqjToEIsULDsYYENu6K0uVpTGmCW4ZtxSJ9bieu4z4fqlyHRo)

[image]

---

Explanation:

Prints `1` a total of `n` times.

[image: Trace]

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 63 bytes

```python
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
output = '1' * n
print(output)
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! I've edited your answer to add code formatting and a header. This site's for Code Golf, where the goal is to have the shortest code, so you might want to remove the extra newline after the import and shorten `output` to `o`

Comment: `print('1'*n)` rather than `output = '1' * n ; print(output)` would be shorter. Remember: Code golf challenge is to make code as short as possible while still fulfilling the requirements while ignoring readability and other things.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 21 Bytes

```
0::=x
1::=x*
*x::=x**
```

Input is on the state and in binary, output is some number of xs (can be ignored) and the output number of asterisks on the state at the end.

Is this allowed?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 do they have to be? If so, can I require a bracket to be at the beginning of input?

Comment: Thought about it: No and No. I didn't have this rule in the original question so you don't have to always output the same starting characters. Input is a number.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 33 bytes

```swift
let u={for _ in 1...$0{print(0)}}
```

The "grouping separator" here is a newline after every digit.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 3 bytes

```
⍴∘0
```

This reshapes `0` to have the same length as the argument to the function, effectively repeating it input times.

For the same length, there's also `/∘0` and `⌿∘0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 7 bytes

```perl
$_=1x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tawQiX@/39DLkMjLgMuYyMuIwMY@JdfUJKZn1f8XzenAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 6 bytes

```powershell
'1'*$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmfVpqXXJKZn6eQpqGSp1n9X91QXUsl738tV5qGsZHmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 5 bytes

```scala
"1"*_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4W7SSbmpFQU5iZp6SjpJuXn55YlGeUuzNnvykrNTkEgVfoIRCNZeCQkpqmkIukKORWJRebKXgWFSUWBkdXFKUmZceq2mlEJqXWaJgC1apoFAAFC3JydNI0zDU1EQTMcAQMYQI1XIBibLEHIU0KwUNz7wSWzuI6ZoKtktLS9J0LZYqGSppxUPYC2sh9IIFEBoA)